# How to modify a text file?

Tags: python, file, text

I'm using Python, and would like to insert a string into a text file without deleting or copying the file. How can I do that?

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1325927/2276527) answer by Alex Martelli.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4358169/538284

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing on the topmost row of a csv file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824439/writing-on-the-topmost-row-of-a-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: @Ani the other post *is* a duplicate of [Inserting Line at Specified Position of a Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1325905) anyway and certainly there are clear composed answers here, Why not add your answer here instead of the other way? Accepted answer is *not* a requirement for a good question.

Comment: @BhargavRao Vote retracted. I should have found that duplicate though!

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/1325927/2276527

Answer (score 163):

Unfortunately there is no way to insert into the middle of a file without re-writing it. As previous posters have indicated, you can append to a file or overwrite part of it using seek but if you want to add stuff at the beginning or the middle, you'll have to rewrite it.

This is an operating system thing, not a Python thing. It is the same in all languages.

What I usually do is read from the file, make the modifications and write it out to a new file called myfile.txt.tmp or something like that. This is better than reading the whole file into memory because the file may be too large for that. Once the temporary file is completed, I rename it the same as the original file.

This is a good, safe way to do it because if the file write crashes or aborts for any reason, you still have your untouched original file.

Comment: Do unix tools like awk/sed do something similar in their code?

Comment: It's not true that this is the same in all languages. In ActionScript:

fileStream.openAsync(filename,FileMode.UPDATE); 

Then I can go anywhere in the file I want and change anything.

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin Do you know what system calls ActionScript is making? Is there a possibility that openAsync reads the file and writes a new one after the call?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins I do not. However, I do know that it isn't reading the entire file into memory, as I have used it to handle filesizes of several GB. I suspect it's the same as writing with C# streamwriter. I view python as a tool for doing small things quickly, rather than large scale development and file manipulation.

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin, the user isn't asking about seeking around in the file and changing it (every language I know of can do that); he is asking about inserting text, which is different than simply changing/overwriting what is already in the file. Maybe in practical application it is different, but nothing I can find in the [ActionScript API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) indicates that it behaves any different from any other language in this regard.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I thought it was the same thing - FileStream.writeUTF

Answer (score 142):

Depends on what you want to do.  To append you can open it with "a":

```
 with open("foo.txt", "a") as f:
     f.write("new line\n")
```

If you want to preprend something you have to read from the file first:

```
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as f:
     old = f.read() # read everything in the file
     f.seek(0) # rewind
     f.write("new line\n" + old) # write the new line before
```

Comment: Just a small addition, to use the `with` statement in Python 2.5 you need to add "from __future__ import with_statement". Other than that, opening files with the `with` statement is definitely more readable and less error-prone than manual closing.

Comment: You might consider the `fileinput` helper lib with handles the dirty open/read/modify/write/replace routine nicely when using the `inline=True` arg. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2363893/47390

Comment: It's not a style I use, D.Rosado, but when using the  with  style, I don't think you need to manually close.  The with keeps track of the resource it creates.

Comment: You *do not* need to manually close the file.  That's the whole point of using "with" here.  (Well, actually, Python does this as soon as the file object is garbage collected, which in CPython happens when the name bound to it goes out of scope... but other implementations don't, and CPython might stop doing it some day, so "with" is recommended)

Comment: Can we replace some characters in it?

Comment: Note that if new text is smaller than the original file, you must call `f.truncate()` after f.seek; otherwise you'll end up with random garbage from the original file at the end.

Answer (score 84):

The [**`fileinput`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module of the Python standard library will rewrite a file inplace if you use the inplace=1 parameter:

```
import sys
import fileinput

# replace all occurrences of 'sit' with 'SIT' and insert a line after the 5th
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('lorem_ipsum.txt', inplace=1)):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('sit', 'SIT'))  # replace 'sit' and write
    if i == 4: sys.stdout.write('\n')  # write a blank line after the 5th line
```

Comment: How is this expected to work in python3? I just ported an app that had some code like this from python to python3 and I just could not get this to work right at all. The 'line' variable is a bytes type, I tried decoding it into unicode and then modifying it and then encoding it back to bytes but it just would not work right. It raised some exception I can't remember off the top of my head. Are people using fileinput inplace=1 in python3 with any success?

Comment: @Robru: here's [Python 3 code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/4279)

Comment: But its no problem cos you tested it first on an unimportant file right?

Answer (score 34):

Rewriting a file in place is often done by saving the old copy with a modified name.  Unix folks add a `~` to mark the old one.  Windows folks do all kinds of things -- add .bak or .old -- or rename the file entirely or put the ~ on the front of the name.

```py
import shutil
shutil.move(afile, afile + "~")

destination= open(aFile, "w")
source= open(aFile + "~", "r")
for line in source:
    destination.write(line)
    if <some condition>:
        destination.write(<some additional line> + "\n")

source.close()
destination.close()
```

Instead of `shutil`, you can use the following.

```
import os
os.rename(aFile, aFile + "~")
```

Comment: Looks good.  Wondering if .readlines() is better than iterating the source?

Comment: @bozdoz: iterating is better since readlines reads the whole file.  Not good for big files.  Of course, this presumes that you can do your modifications in such a localized way.  Sometimes you can't, or your code gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: @S.Lott: `os.rename(aFile, aFile + "~")` will modify the name of the source file, not creating a copy.

Answer (score 15):

Python's mmap module will allow you to insert into a file. The following sample shows how it can be done in Unix (Windows mmap may be different). Note that this does not handle all error conditions and you might corrupt or lose the original file. Also, this won't handle unicode strings.

```
import os
from mmap import mmap

def insert(filename, str, pos):
    if len(str) < 1:
        # nothing to insert
        return

    f = open(filename, 'r+')
    m = mmap(f.fileno(), os.path.getsize(filename))
    origSize = m.size()

    # or this could be an error
    if pos > origSize:
        pos = origSize
    elif pos < 0:
        pos = 0

    m.resize(origSize + len(str))
    m[pos+len(str):] = m[pos:origSize]
    m[pos:pos+len(str)] = str
    m.close()
    f.close()
```

It is also possible to do this without mmap with files opened in 'r+' mode, but it is less convenient and less efficient as you'd have to read and temporarily store the contents of the file from the insertion position to EOF - which might be huge.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by Adam you have to take your system limitations into consideration before you can decide on approach whether you have enough memory to read it all into memory replace parts of it and re-write it.

If you're dealing with a small file or have no memory issues this might help:

**Option 1)**
Read entire file into memory, do a regex substitution on the entire or part of the line and replace it with that line plus the extra line. You will need to make sure that the 'middle line' is unique in the file or if you have timestamps on each line this should be pretty reliable.

```
# open file with r+b (allow write and binary mode)
f = open("file.log", 'r+b')   
# read entire content of file into memory
f_content = f.read()
# basically match middle line and replace it with itself and the extra line
f_content = re.sub(r'(middle line)', r'\1\nnew line', f_content)
# return pointer to top of file so we can re-write the content with replaced string
f.seek(0)
# clear file content 
f.truncate()
# re-write the content with the updated content
f.write(f_content)
# close file
f.close()
```

**Option 2)**
Figure out middle line, and replace it with that line plus the extra line.

```
# open file with r+b (allow write and binary mode)
f = open("file.log" , 'r+b')   
# get array of lines
f_content = f.readlines()
# get middle line
middle_line = len(f_content)/2
# overwrite middle line
f_content[middle_line] += "\nnew line"
# return pointer to top of file so we can re-write the content with replaced string
f.seek(0)
# clear file content 
f.truncate()
# re-write the content with the updated content
f.write(''.join(f_content))
# close file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a small class for doing this cleanly.

```
import tempfile

class FileModifierError(Exception):
    pass

class FileModifier(object):

    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.__write_dict = {}
        self.__filename = fname
        self.__tempfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        with open(fname, 'rb') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                self.__tempfile.write(line)
        self.__tempfile.seek(0)

    def write(self, s, line_number = 'END'):
        if line_number != 'END' and not isinstance(line_number, (int, float)):
            raise FileModifierError("Line number %s is not a valid number" % line_number)
        try:
            self.__write_dict[line_number].append(s)
        except KeyError:
            self.__write_dict[line_number] = [s]

    def writeline(self, s, line_number = 'END'):
        self.write('%s\n' % s, line_number)

    def writelines(self, s, line_number = 'END'):
        for ln in s:
            self.writeline(s, line_number)

    def __popline(self, index, fp):
        try:
            ilines = self.__write_dict.pop(index)
            for line in ilines:
                fp.write(line)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def close(self):
        self.__exit__(None, None, None)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        with open(self.__filename,'w') as fp:
            for index, line in enumerate(self.__tempfile.readlines()):
                self.__popline(index, fp)
                fp.write(line)
            for index in sorted(self.__write_dict):
                for line in self.__write_dict[index]:
                    fp.write(line)
        self.__tempfile.close()
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
with FileModifier(filename) as fp:
    fp.writeline("String 1", 0)
    fp.writeline("String 2", 20)
    fp.writeline("String 3")  # To write at the end of the file
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me personally, it does add text to the file but it removes everything first!

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't work at all. Shame, because it seemed like a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

If you know some unix you could try the following:

Notes: $ means the command prompt

Say you have a file my_data.txt with content as such:

```
$ cat my_data.txt
This is a data file
with all of my data in it.
```

Then using the `os` module you can use the usual `sed` commands

```
import os

# Identifiers used are:
my_data_file = "my_data.txt"
command = "sed -i 's/all/none/' my_data.txt"

# Execute the command
os.system(command)
```

If you aren't aware of sed, check it out, it is extremely useful.

Comment: It's not Pythonic at all