# What is the best way to change text contained in an XML file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, text

Let's say I have an existing trivial XML file named 'MyData.xml' that contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<myElement>foo</myElement>
```

I want to change the text value of 'foo' to 'bar' resulting in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<myElement>bar</myElement>
```

Once I am done, I want to save the changes.

What is the easiest and simplest way to accomplish all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Python's [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Basically you will take the following steps:

1. Read XML data into DOM object
2. Use DOM methods to modify the document
3. Save new DOM object to new XML document

The python spec should hold your hand rather nicely though this process.

Comment: So, for # 3 would I have explicitly overwrite the existing file versus using some built-in function in minidom that might implicitly do that for me?

Comment: Ray: yes, any DOM manipulations will be in-memory only. You'll have to copy to a new file or overwrite the existing file. For tips on how to handle modifying an existing file, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python

Answer (score 3):

For quick, non-critical XML manipulations, i really like [P4X](http://ponderer.org/p4x). It let's you write like this:

```python
import p4x
doc = p4x.P4X (open(file).read)
doc.myElement = 'bar'
```

Comment: the current version of this (last updated 2005) gives a syntax error when importing into Python 2.7.2. Can't use it as is.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I wrote based on [@Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179287/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-text-contained-in-an-xml-file-using-python#179306):

```python
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os

# create a backup of original file
new_file_name = 'MyData.xml'
old_file_name = new_file_name + "~"
os.rename(new_file_name, old_file_name)

# change text value of element
doc = parse(old_file_name)
node = doc.getElementsByTagName('myElement')
node[0].firstChild.nodeValue = 'bar'

# persist changes to new file
xml_file = open(new_file_name, "w")
doc.writexml(xml_file, encoding="utf-8")
xml_file.close()
```

Not sure if this was the easiest and simplest approach but it does work. ([@Javier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179287/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-text-contained-in-an-xml-file-using-python#179305) has less lines of code but requires non-standard library)

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to check out Uche Ogbuji's excellent XML Data Binding Library, Amara:
http://uche.ogbuji.net/tech/4suite/amara

(Documentation here:
http://platea.pntic.mec.es/~jmorilla/amara/manual/)

The cool thing about Amara is that it turns an XML document in to a Python object, so you can just do stuff like:

```python
record = doc.xml_create_element(u'Record')

nameElem = doc.xml_create_element(u'Name', content=unicode(name))

record.xml_append(nameElem)

valueElem = doc.xml_create_element(u'Value', content=unicode(value))

record.xml_append(valueElem
```

(which creates a Record element that contains Name and Value elements (which in turn contain the values of the name and value variables)).