# Paste strings into larger string in Python

Tags: python, replace

I have a pretty large logfile (1.3G) which is more or less tabular with spaces padding the individual fields. I also have a list of indices in that file where I would like to overwrite a field's contents with some other string. For the sake of simplicity, assume that the field is previously empty and my replacement is not too long for the cell, so I only have to replace `len(replacement)` characters starting at `index` with `replacement`.

The number of replacements I need to perform in that file is around 10'000. How do I do this efficiently? Does Python have a data structure like a C array where I can just overwrite data?

Comment: You could use a `bytearray`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572624/mutable-strings-in-python (that would answer your literal question). However, it might be more "efficient" (depending on how you define that) to not load the entire file into memory but to read and write it line by line.

Comment: Perhaps take 2 or 3 lines from the log and show us the before and after.

Comment: Maybe also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508983/how-to-overwrite-some-bytes-in-the-middle-of-a-file-with-python

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti The real log is too complex to paste, but assume sth like: `AAAAA  BBBBB  CCCCC\nAAAAA  -      DDDDD\nAAAAA  EEEEE  -     \n` and so on. Put simply, now have a list of all indices of `-` in the string (in reality it's not a simple dash but a complex regular expression with lookarounds) and want to paste `XXnnn` in the place of the dash, overwriting as many spaces that follow the dash as necessary.

Comment: @FelixDombek provide an *example in the question itself*. Give example inputs and example outputs. And I suppose, the point is you are trying to create *a new file* with the replacements?

Comment: You can open the file in update mode, seek to a given location in the file, `write()` some text, and it will overwrite the existing contents.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The task is really not tied to the actual contents of the log. I'm very simply looking to do exactly what is done in the post that mkrieger1 linked. Seek, write. But not on an actual file, but on data in memory.

Comment: I have a solution now using `content_array = bytearray(content)` and then in a loop `content_array[index:index+replace_len] = replace_str`. And it's super fast, so exactly what I was looking for. Thanks everyone!