# Navigating through text file in python

Tags: python, text, line

I have a text file which contains the following:

```
NUM,123
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BACON
CAR
NUM,456
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BURGER
CAR
NUM,789
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,SAUSAGE
CAR
```

I'm trying to change `BURGER` but how to do that?

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r')
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if '456' in line:
        print line
        break
```

With the above code, I want to pinpoint it using the distinct number after `NUM`, but I am only able to read the line where `456` occurs. How to read 3 lines below `456` and then access the `BURGER` part?

Thanks!

Update using Levon's solution:

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        if '456' in line:
            field = ','.join(data[i+3].split(',')[1])
            field = field.replace(field,'PIZZA')
```

Now how do you write everything back into a new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** based on comment below:

Use this code if all of the file can fit into memory (reads *all* of file at once):

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        if "456" in line:
            print data[i+3].split(',')[1],
```

We read the whole file into a list (`data`), and then use [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to access both the index (`i`), and the element at the given index (ie. the `line`). Since we have all of the data in the list, once we find the line with "456" we can look for the line at `i + 3` very easily in our list and use [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to separate out the word we are interested in.

--

Use this code if file is potentially very big (processes file *line-by-line*):

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    count = -1
    for line in f:
        if "456" in line:
            count = 4

        count -= 1
        if count == 0:
            print line.split(',')[1],
```

will print "BURGER"

This looks for the 2nd word, 3 lines after the string "456". It assumes the words are separated by a comma (`,`)

Note that using the `with` construct also takes care of closing the file when we are done (or if we encounter an exception).

Comment: In your case you pinpoint it with the "BURGER", what I'm trying to do is to pinpoint it with the "456" and then read 3 lines below it and replace the "second word" which is "BURGER"

Comment: @user1546610 So you are looking for the 2nd word 3 lines *after* you see the string "456"? But you don't necessarily want to change that string, correct?

Comment: @user1546610 Do you just want to print/access that particular string, and nothing else?

Comment: Yes printing/accessing that one would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: +1, and there's no use overcomplicating things for beginners (I'd use csv/itertools to make a record grouper :^) -- but I always wince a little when I see the 'string in otherstring' construct because of the problem of "NUM,4567".

Comment: @DSM agreed, the "string `in` otherstring" definitely has its limitations/drawbacks, but seemed to work fine here.

Comment: Great update Levon! Now how do you write everything (updated) back to a new file?

Comment: @user1546610 I don't know what you upated :) .. but assuming you changed something in `data` you could write the `data` back this way: `with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfp: outfp.write(''.join(data))` (note the 2nd line is indented below while `with` similarly as above. The output file will be `result.txt`.If this doesn't help, you may want to consider posting a separate/new question.

Comment: I updated my code. If I do like your comment above then it will just write everything back the same like the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    if '456' in line:
        stored_line = line
    if 'BURGER' in line:
        print stored_line
```

This will give you the correct line in the file and you will have access to the number preceding it. To edit the file in place, look to a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325905/inserting-line-at-specified-position-of-a-text-file-in-python/1325927#1325927).

If you are just interested in the text stream. You can you add `line.replace('BURGER', 'FOO')` after the print.

Comment: Slight problem with there being an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your text file has structure. I presume you are really asking for a way to read that structure, for example so that someone is able to change their order to a pizza.

Your input.txt has some orders. Each order starts with an order number (NUM,456 etc.), then some items, then `CAR` as if to show that the person in drive through has finished with their order.

So, step 1.

```
# changes order 456's food to a pizza, from whatever it was
file = open('input.txt', 'r')

bad_order = 'NUM,%d' % 456
new_food = 'FOOD,%s' % 'Pizza'

change = False
for line in file:
  line = line.strip()
  msg = ''
  if line.startswith('NUM,'):
    msg = 'Ignoring order: '
  if line == bad_order:
    msg = 'Changing order: '
    change = True
  if change and line.startswith('FOOD,'):
    line = new_food
  if line == 'CAR':
    change = False
  print '%s%s' % (msg, line)
```

Further steps might be to recognize the structure more formally (eg add orders to a collection for processing later); or refactor this into a function so you can test changing different order numbers and different food types, not just `FOOD`.

*EDIT*

I've edited the code to make it clear how it currently reads your file. The output is now:

```
Ignoring order: NUM,123
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BACON
CAR
Changing order: NUM,456
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,Pizza
CAR
Ignoring order: NUM,789
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,SAUSAGE
CAR
```