# Python urllib wget save complete page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wget, urllib

I would like to download the **Webpage, Complete** with `urllib` or `wget` or a similar package in python.

The resulting html file is *different* for the **Webpage, Complete** than with **Webpage, HTML Only** which is what `wget.download` or `urllib.request.urlopen` seems to be doing.

[image]

Example URL where those two `html` files are different: https://smash.gg/tournament/genesis-6/events/smash-for-switch-singles/brackets/500500/865126.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate pressing the CTRL + s, then s to save (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516590/how-to-save-complete-webpage-not-just-basic-html-using-python))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://smash.gg/tournament/genesis-6/events/smash-for-switch-singles/brackets/500500/865126')

save_me = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up('s')
save_me.perform()
```

Comment: After running your code, I'm not seeing the downloaded files anywhere. Does the ``Enter`` key need to be pressed or something?

Comment: Don't think so. I'll look into this more.

Answer (score 0):

The page you've linked relies very heavily on javascript and more specifically on AJAX requests. `wget` does not parse Javascript at all, so if there are any links within the JS source that are required, Wget will simply skip over them. This is what is causing the differences you noticed.

You will likely not be able to save this page completely with something like wget or urllib. Since they both work primarily with only HTML sources. Wget can handle CSS as well, but that's about it. For a script heavy page, you need something a lot more complex. If you really want to save it programmatically, you need to go with Selenium.