# Add lines to text file after occurence of certain text

Tags: python

I have a text file that I needs to manipulate. I want to add a line after occurence of word "exactarch". Means whenever "exactarch" occurs, I want to add text in the next line.

E.g. If this is the original file content,

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
```

I want to change it as below:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == 'exactarch':  
            f.write('obsoletes=1')
```

Obviously this is not working as I can't figure out how can I count and write to this line.

Comment: Read in the whole file as a list of lines, do your insertion in the list and then write out the whole list to a file

Comment: Are you working on GNU/Linux or some system that has `sed` installed?

Comment: `if line.strip() == 'exactarch=1': `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - read all lines, find correct line and insert desired line after found. Dump result lines to file.

```
import os 
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines.insert(lines.index('exactarch=1\n') + 1, 'obsoletes=1\n')
with open('dst.txt', 'w') as f:
    for l in lines:
        f.write(l)
```

Answer (score 4):

You ask for a Python solution. But tasks like this are made to be solved using simpler tools.

If you are using a system that has [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), you can do this in a simle one-liner:

```
$ sed '/exactarch/aobsoletes=1' < in.txt
```

What does this mean?

- `sed`: the executable
- `/exactarch/`: matches all lines that contain `exactarch`
- `a`: after the current line, *append* a new line with the following text
- `obsoletes=1`: the text to append in a new line

Output:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
```

**Edit:**

To modify the file in place, use the option `-i` and the file as an argument:

```
$ sed -i '/exactarch/aobsoletes=1' in.txt
```

Comment: This just prints output on console. How can I insert in actual file?

Comment: To write the output to a *different* file, add `> out.txt` to the command line. To modify the file in place, use the option `-i`.

Comment: Not working. I am using sed -i '/exactarch/aobsoletes=1' < in.txt. I need to modify the file in place.

Answer (score 2):

[The past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python) says it's pretty simple - replacing words in files is not a new thing.

If you want to replace a word, you can use the solution implemented there. In your context:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(fileToSearch, inplace=True):
    print(line.replace("exactarch", "exactarch\nobsoletes=1"), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hesitant using fileinput, b/c if something goes wrong during the 'analysis' phase you are left with a file in whatever conditions it was left before the failure. I would read everything in, and then do full work on it. The code below ensures that:

- Your inserted value contains a newline value '\n' if it's not going to be the last item.
- Will not add duplicate inserted values by checking the one below it.
- Iterates through all values incase multiple "exactarch=1"s were added since the snippet last ran.

Hope this helps, albeit not as stylish as a one/two liner.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

insertValue = 'obsoletes=1'

for item in data:
    if item.rstrip() == 'exactarch=1': #find it if it's in the middle or the last line (ie. no '\n')
        point = data.index(item)

        if point+1 == len(data): #Will be inserted as new line since current exactarch=1 is in last position, so you don't want the '\n', right?
            data.insert(point+1, instertValue)
        else:
            if data[point + 1].rstrip() != insertValue: #make sure the value isn't already below exactarch=1
                data.insert(point+1, insertValue + '\n')
                print('insertValue added below "exactarch=1"')
            else:
                print('insertValue already exists below exactarch=1')

with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(data)
```