# Python replace word for line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def false_to_true():
    name = input("Input name: ")
    file=open("users.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    for line in lines:
        username, lel, type = line.split("/")
#This while dont work, work only for last line in text. How to fix
        while name == username:
            name = input("input name again: ")

    type = "True"
    with open("users.txt", "w") as users:
        users.write("/".join([username, lel, type]))

false_to_true()
```

I won't to change word False to True for username I input.
I have this text in file users:

```
#Marko123/male/False
#Mimi007/female/False
#John33/male/False
#Lisa12/female/False
#Inna23/female/False
#Alisa27/female/False
```

When i input username  Lisa12, i wont to got this text:

```
#Marko123/male/False
#Mimi007/female/False
#John33/male/False
#Lisa12/female/True    -here-
#Inna23/female/False
#Alisa27/female/False
```

Comment: This has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582835/change-text-in-file-with-python/34583103.

Comment: Why do you need the `while`?

Comment: ok should i delete question?

Comment: I need because while because  if there is no typed name in the file , to request again that typed name.

Comment: Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582835/change-text-in-file-with-python