# How to replace contents of column in one file with that of another file based on key variable?

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I'd like to use a script to do the following. I have two files. I'd like to replace the contents of column 2 ("A1" in the example below) and 3 ("A2" in the example below) in file2 with the contents of column 2 ("A1_new" in the example below) and 3 ("A2_new" in the example below) in file1. There are two conditions:

- This has to be done based on a key-variable ("SNP" in the examples below) which is present in both files in column 1. Meaning: the script should check the presence of key-variable X in file1 and file2 and then replace the contents of file2 with file1 as described above. If there is no match, nothing should be done.
- Both files are very large: file2 is about 38Gb in size (1,529 columns and ~8.3 million rows), file1 is smaller as it only has 6 columns instead of 1,529.
- I can make file1 such that it will only contain the changes to be implemented. The number of rows would then be around 8,000 I guesstimate.
- I should also note that the *number* of keys isn't necessarily equal nor in sorted in the same order!

Below I have put the heads of the two files. So the expected result would look like this for the_new_file2:

> SNP A1 A2 UPID00126-UPID00126-A318-0034 UPID01799-UPID01799-A318-0492 UPID01890-UPID01890-A318-0151 UPID00306-UPID00306-A318-0245 UPID00629-UPID00629-A318-0033 UPID01934-UPID01934-A318-0215 UPID00526-UPID00526-A318-0526
>   rs12565286 C G 0.0190125 0.0339966 0.0130005 0.00500488 0.0109863 0.0180054 0.00500488
>   rs11804171 A T 0.0249939 0.154999 0.0310059 0.0169983 0.0159912 0.0230103 0.0159912
>   rs2977670 C G 1.95801 1.745 1.31201 1.97299 1.97198 1.96301 1.97299
>   rs143225517 C T 0 0.93399 0.989014 0 0 0 0
>   rs3094315 A G 2 1 1 2 2 2 2
>   rs3131972 G A 1.99701 0.997009 0.997986 1.99701 1.99499 1.987 1.99701
>   rs3131971 C T 1.89301 1.07901 1.08902 1.98901 1.86801 1.92798 1.982
>   rs2073814 G C 1.98001 0.983002 0.993988 1.97601 1.98401 1.979 1.97601
>   rs2073813 A G 0.00299072 0.915039 0.899017 0.00299072 0.00299072 0.00201416 0.00299072
>   rs3131969 G A 1.996 1.03097 1.09598 1.99701 1.99701 1.99701 1.996
>   rs3131968 G A 1.996 1.02801 1.09396 1.996 1.99701 1.99701 1.99499
>   rs3131967 C T 1.931 1.01202 1.08701 1.98999 1.93298 1.97101 1.987
>   rs3115859 A G 1.996 1.02502 1.09497 1.99701 1.99399 1.98599 1.991
>   rs34927559 G A 1.91898 1.61298 1.845 1.91901 1.94299 1.77402 1.952
>   rs115173026 T G 0.423004 0.420013 0.11499 1.09097 0.51001 0.618988 0.114013
>   **chr1:956061:I I D** 0.356018 0.395996 0.10202 1.09903 0.530975 0.505005 0.0679932
>   rs116130865 T C 0.420014 0.420013 0.113983 1.09003 0.503968 0.535004 0.11203
>   rs111893801 T C 0.0239868 0.0180054 0.00601196 0.0209961 0.019989 0.0610046 0.00299072

You can see in bold in the above "expected result" and below in the `head` of file1 and file2 that columns 2 and 2 for key "chr1:956061:I" changed. From "AG G" to "I D".

I do have some experience in bash. But I'm thinking `awk` will be quite slow, and probably `perl` or `python` might be much faster. I've seen something here: [[How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python). But that is just replacing, and not based on a key-variable.

It would be awesome if someone can give me some pointers on how to go about this.

Thanks!

---

Upon popular request below the `head` of file 1 and file 2.

***Head file1***

> SNP A1_new A2_new
>   **chr1:956061:I I D**
>   chr1:3716325:I I D
>   chr1:4095845:I I D
>   chr1:4097079:I I D

***Head file2***

> SNP A1 A2 UPID00126-UPID00126-A318-0034 UPID01799-UPID01799-A318-0492 UPID01890-UPID01890-A318-0151 UPID00306-UPID00306-A318-0245 UPID00629-UPID00629-A318-0033 UPID01934-UPID01934-A318-0215 UPID00526-UPID00526-A318-0526
>   rs12565286 C G 0.0190125 0.0339966 0.0130005 0.00500488 0.0109863 0.0180054 0.00500488
>   rs11804171 A T 0.0249939 0.154999 0.0310059 0.0169983 0.0159912 0.0230103 0.0159912
>   rs2977670 C G 1.95801 1.745 1.31201 1.97299 1.97198 1.96301 1.97299
>   rs143225517 C T 0 0.93399 0.989014 0 0 0 0
>   rs3094315 A G 2 1 1 2 2 2 2
>   rs3131972 G A 1.99701 0.997009 0.997986 1.99701 1.99499 1.987 1.99701
>   rs3131971 C T 1.89301 1.07901 1.08902 1.98901 1.86801 1.92798 1.982
>   rs2073814 G C 1.98001 0.983002 0.993988 1.97601 1.98401 1.979 1.97601
>   rs2073813 A G 0.00299072 0.915039 0.899017 0.00299072 0.00299072 0.00201416 0.00299072
>   rs3131969 G A 1.996 1.03097 1.09598 1.99701 1.99701 1.99701 1.996
>   rs3131968 G A 1.996 1.02801 1.09396 1.996 1.99701 1.99701 1.99499
>   rs3131967 C T 1.931 1.01202 1.08701 1.98999 1.93298 1.97101 1.987
>   rs3115859 A G 1.996 1.02502 1.09497 1.99701 1.99399 1.98599 1.991
>   rs34927559 G A 1.91898 1.61298 1.845 1.91901 1.94299 1.77402 1.952
>   rs115173026 T G 0.423004 0.420013 0.11499 1.09097 0.51001 0.618988 0.114013
>   **chr1:956061:I AG A** 0.356018 0.395996 0.10202 1.09903 0.530975 0.505005 0.0679932
>   rs116130865 T C 0.420014 0.420013 0.113983 1.09003 0.503968 0.535004 0.11203
>   rs111893801 T C 0.0239868 0.0180054 0.00601196 0.0209961 0.019989 0.0610046 0.00299072
>   rs9777931 T C 1.54102 1.27399 1.75003 0.863983 1.46597 1.33801 1.07199
>   rs3121553 C G 0.419007 0.364014 0.112976 1.08801 0.562989 0.546997 0.110016
>   rs809912 T C 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs196128 G T 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs262676 A T 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs196127 A T 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs149435595 C A 0.019989 0.0509949 0.478027 0.0580139 0.337006 0.0169983 0.705994
>   rs12082939 T C 1.021 1.17899 0.442963 1.22 1.008 0.00900269 1.056
>   rs262675 G A 0.998993 0.822998 0 1 0.997986 0 0.971985
>   rs262672 T G 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs262671 A C 1 1 0 1 0.997986 0 1
>   rs3107126 A C 0 0 0.0039978 0.0119934 0 0.00100708 0.0150146
>   rs11583093 A G 0.00799561 0.184998 0.0130005 0.00698853 0 0.0159912 0.00900269
>   rs262670 T C 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs262669 A G 1 1 0.0039978 1.01199 1 0 1.01501
>   rs9442619 T C 0 0 0.0039978 0.0109863 0 0 0.0150146
>   rs2257182 C T 1.021 1.17899 0.442963 1.22 1.008 0.00900269 1.056
>   rs262668 G A 1 1 0.0039978 1.01199 1 0 1.01501
>   rs262667 C T 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs34944978 A G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs262665 G A 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs262664 C G 1 1 0.0039978 1.01199 1 0 1.01501
>   rs2503704 C T 1.43301 1.43503 1.28302 1.5 1.86999 1.444 1.85998
>   rs262663 C T 1 1 0.0039978 1.01199 1 0.00100708 1.01501
>   rs262662 G A 1 1 0.0039978 1.01199 1 0 1.01501
>   rs3107125 A G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs2459984 G A 1.021 1.17899 0.442963 1.22 1.008 0.00799561 1.056
>   rs61776606 A G 0.0169983 0 0.00299072 0.0289917 0.00601196 0.676025 0
>   rs2459983 G A 1.39798 1.858 1.871 1.798 1.91199 1.54697 1.92499
>   rs262661 C T 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs262660 G A 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   chr1:2087094:I AATG A 0.997986 1.00101 0.00900269 1.04199 1 0.00201416 1.01599
>   rs3123592 C T 0 0 0.0039978 0.0109863 0 0 0.0159912
>   rs381664 G A 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
>   rs72629470 A G 1 1 0 1.00101 0 0 0
>   rs151048557 T C 0.0039978 0 0 0.00201416 0.0180054 0.00100708 0
>   rs72629471 G C 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629472 C G 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs116329948 T C 0 0.266998 0 0 0 0.0039978 0
>   rs16823335 A G 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12028094 T C 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs141183701 T C 0 0 0.00201416 0 0.00100708 0.00299072 0.0150146
>   rs10797377 A G 1 1.004 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629473 A G 0.00201416 0 0 0.985992 0 0 0
>   rs12063869 A T 1 1.004 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs2889476 C T 1.08701 1.30301 0.019989 1.004 0.052002 0.00299072 0.0100098
>   rs946175 G A 1.08801 1.30301 0.019989 1.004 0.052002 0.00299072 0.00900269
>   rs946176 T C 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs946177 G A 1.08701 1.302 0.019989 1.004 0.052002 0.00299072 0.00900269
>   rs61763644 T C 0.0710144 0.0039978 0.0690002 0.0209961 0.00100708 0 0
>   rs2027262 C T 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs2027263 G A 1 1.004 0 1 0.00100708 0 0
>   rs2027264 A G 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs111412502 T C 1 1.00201 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs11802804 G T 1 1.00699 0 1 0.00100708 0 0
>   rs111668563 G T 1 0.944 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs112539394 A G 1 0.941986 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12028439 G A 1.00601 1.01001 0 1.00201 0.00100708 0 0
>   rs12024879 A G 1 1.00903 0 1 0.00100708 0 0
>   rs12027818 T C 1.02399 1.013 0.00100708 1.03799 0.131989 0 0.00100708
>   rs6685625 C T 0.109985 0.0169983 0.00799561 0.131012 0.0390015 0.00299072 0.14801
>   rs12027883 T C 1 1.00998 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs7534897 T C 0.0130005 0.596985 0.562012 0.00500488 0.0159912 1.11197 0.317993
>   rs6681651 T C 1.09698 1.591 0.0390015 1.01999 0.0539856 0.00201416 0.00900269
>   rs6691208 A C 1.091 1.65201 0.019989 1.005 0.0539856 0.00299072 0.00799561
>   rs4357486 C G 1 1.04901 0.0700073 1 0 0 0.00299072
>   rs4486390 T C 1 1.04901 0.0700073 1 0 0 0.00299072
>   rs7536203 A G 0.437012 0 0.00100708 0.0119934 0.148987 0.00201416 0
>   rs59869348 C T 1.091 1.629 0.019989 1.004 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs59041920 T C 1.091 1.629 0.0190125 1.004 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs60366070 T C 0.0910034 0.604034 0.019989 0.00500488 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs56401121 A G 0.0910034 0.604034 0.019989 0.00500488 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs72629480 T C 1 1.061 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs58317195 G A 0.0910034 0.60498 0.019989 0.00500488 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs114933164 C A 0.645996 0.54602 0.0190125 0.0039978 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00698853
>   rs6680039 G C 0.0920105 0.603027 0.0190125 0.00500488 0.0549927 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs114412925 A G 0.0270081 0 0 0.0450134 0.131012 0 0
>   rs6680573 G C 1.09201 1.67703 0.0190125 1.005 0.0559998 0.00201416 0.00799561
>   rs56200661 T C 1 0.0039978 0 0.919006 0 0 0
>   rs72629481 A G 1 0.0039978 0 0.919006 0 0 0
>   rs17389878 A G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs116142632 T G 0.00500488 0.00201416 0.274994 0 0.00799561 0.567017 0.127991
>   rs16823357 C T 0 0.609985 0 0 0.00100708 0 0.00100708
>   rs12564456 G C 1 1.974 0 1 0.00100708 0.00100708 0.00201416
>   rs55949537 T A 1 1.978 0 1.00201 0.00100708 0 0.00201416
>   rs55784203 T G 1 1.98001 0 1.00201 0.00100708 0 0.00201416
>   rs56091202 G A 1 1.98001 0 1.00201 0.00100708 0 0.00201416
>   rs10909862 A G 1 0.0190125 2 0.989014 1.99799 1.99799 1.99701
>   rs10492936 A G 0 0.615021 0 0 0 0 0.00201416
>   rs67758087 G A 1 1.98401 0 1.00201 0.00100708 0 0.00201416
>   rs12033927 G A 1 1.37503 0 1.00101 0 0 0
>   rs12034794 G T 1 1.98999 0 1.00201 0.00100708 0 0.00201416
>   rs4576609 T C 1 1.99301 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs3795262 G T 1 1.98901 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs3795263 A G 0.0950012 0 0.453033 0.627014 1.10703 0.880981 0.627991
>   rs55873718 G A 1 1.996 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs61763646 A G 0.052002 0 0.0910034 0.0209961 0.0039978 0 0
>   rs56176404 G A 1 1.38098 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs7412983 C A 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs58265521 A C 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs117759489 A C 0.00201416 0 0.0039978 0.0119934 0.00201416 0 0
>   rs60287244 G A 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12034766 G A 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12033401 T C 1 1.35101 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs2142569 A G 0.105988 0 1.00403 0.628998 1.11801 1.992 0.930023
>   rs143965216 T C 0 0 0.00100708 0 0 0 0
>   rs57893585 A T 1 1.99799 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs189380075 G C 0 0.00299072 0.026001 0.00100708 0 0 0
>   rs6693975 A G 1 1.362 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs6693982 A G 0.878998 1.991 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs141204614 T G 0.00500488 0.00100708 0.276001 0 0.00799561 1.05502 0.130005
>   rs12038530 A T 1 1.99799 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12037307 A C 1 1.35101 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12039548 C T 1 1.99899 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12034573 A G 1 1.99899 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs10909864 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs1890338 T C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs58311021 A G 0 0.621979 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs12039132 T C 1 1.97199 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs7514166 C G 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs34408665 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs58052947 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs56398543 A G 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs6661908 A G 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs41334845 T G 1 0.269012 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs6679678 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12042403 C T 0.45401 1.99799 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12041583 G A 0.45401 1.99799 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12041634 T A 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12040299 T C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs10489589 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629493 A G 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629494 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12408197 T C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs67025412 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs10489588 A G 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs67630839 T C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs78841195 G A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs1005471 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs9660819 T C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs9661525 G T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629496 A G 1 0.269012 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs16823392 G C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs116556794 T C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs74048148 G A 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs77415878 G C 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs113272167 T C 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs112690788 G A 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72856433 A G 1 1.99701 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629497 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs67872056 T C 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs72629498 T C 1 1.35199 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs67289919 A G 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs67919793 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs67908307 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs75400926 C T 0.877991 1.82599 0 0.928009 0 0 0
>   rs12036378 A G 1 2 0.00100708 1 0 0 0
>   rs55863899 G C 1 0.268005 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs74048152 T G 0 0.64801 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs66693767 G A 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs10909865 G A 1 2 0.00299072 1 0 0 0
>   rs72856440 G A 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs2993510 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs113884577 A G 0.0180054 0 0.0039978 0.0239868 0.0039978 0 0
>   rs12567620 G T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12566487 A G 0 0.64801 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs12409277 C T 1 2 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12044162 G A 1 1.992 0 1 0 0 0
>   rs12724379 A C 0.00100708 0 0.312988 0.0039978 0.00100708 0 0
>   rs6684233 A C 0 0.650024 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs6692292 C T 1 1.93701 0 1 0.00201416 0 0
>   rs56213325 A G 0.0039978 0 0 0.0190125 0.00100708 0.00100708 0.00201416
>   rs12045368 G A 1 1.28 0 1 0.00201416 0 0
>   chr1:2960196:I TCAAACAAA T 1 1.931 0 0.98999 0.00201416 0 0
>   rs10909866 T C 1 1.92801 0 1 0.00201416 0 0
>   rs12046233 G A 1 1.28 0 1 0.00201416 0 0
>   rs12044848 T C 1 1.92499 0 1 0.00201416 0 0
>   rs12120940 A G 0.0150146 0.0180054 0.0710144 0.0299988 0.0100098 0.0820007 0.00900269
>   rs2651900 T G 0.388 0.0039978 0.665985 0.230011 0.600006 0 0.21698
>   rs2075968 T C 0.442993 0 0.312988 0.756989 0.320007 0 0.888001
>   rs1627080 C T 1.00201 0.0969849 1.009 1.008 1 0.00799561 2
>   rs116609258 A C 0.0820007 0 0.556 0.00900269 0.0830078 0 0.019989
>   rs117719590 C T 0.0830078 0 0.0230103 0.0100098 0.0710144 0 0.871978
>   rs2817128 C T 2 2 2 2 1.99799 2 1.91199
>   rs2817129 C G 1.68399 1.923 1.327 1.867 1.48898 1.99399 1.84402
>   rs79551700 T C 0.07901 0.00100708 0.0039978 0.0429993 0.0570068 0.00201416 0.0320129
>   rs35019643 G C 0.07901 0.00100708 0.0039978 0.0429993 0.0570068 0.00201416 0.0320129
>   chr1:3089167:I CG C 0.07901 0.00100708 0.0039978 0.0429993 0.0570068 0.00201416 0.0320129
>   rs34503920 T C 0.07901 0.00201416 0.0039978 0.0429993 0.0570068 0.00201416 0.0320129
>   rs2455110 A G 0.132995 0.0329895 0.0870361 0.0930176 0.510986 0.137024 0.052002
>   rs56788035 A G 0.0700074 0.00799561 0.0629883 0.0209961 0.427032 0.0799866 0.0409851
>   rs2455109 T A 0.15799 0.0549927 0.0950317 0.557984 0.529023 0.150024 0.10199
>   rs11807062 C A 0.15799 0.332031 0.0940246 0.543 0.526001 0.150024 0.0969849
>   rs60951434 A G 0.0700074 0.00799561 0.0629883 0.0220032 0.485992 0.0799866 0.0409851
>   rs113002511 G A 0.00100708 0.00799561 0.00601196 0.0100098 0.0100098 0.0100098 0.00201416
>   rs4648372 G A 0.156983 0.32901 0.0950317 0.55603 0.473999 0.0809937 0.0960083
>   rs4648373 T C 0.156983 0.32901 0.0940246 0.548981 0.466003 0.0809937 0.0549927
>   rs10909907 G A 0.165009 0.32901 0.0950317 0.55603 0.843994 0.0849915 0.0950012
>   rs2249336 C T 0.132995 0.307984 0.0910339 0.107971 0.46698 0.0700073 0.0539856
>   rs2249319 T C 0.0710144 0.00799561 0.0650024 0.0239868 0.437988 0.0150146 0.0400085
>   rs2249318 T C 0.0710144 0.00799561 0.0650024 0.0239868 0.437988 0.0150146 0.0400085
>   rs2455112 G A 0.413971 0.323975 0.36502 0.163025 0.5 0.369018 1.13498
>   rs12755504 G A 0.0419922 0.00799561 0.0599976 0.026001 0.378021 0.0130005 0.0390015
>   rs12071366 G C 1 0 0.00100708 0 0 0 0
>   rs6424052 G A 0 0.998993 0.0509949 1.98901 0 0 0.993988
>   rs7543006 G C 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   rs56710549 G C 0 0 0.234985 0 0 0 0
>   rs140255410 A G 0 0.00601196 0.0130005 0 0.0190125 0.00201416 0.00299072
>   rs111484302 G A 0 0 0.467987 0 0 0 0
>   rs9424286 T G 0.0100098 0 0.0379944 0 0 0 0.00299072
>   rs112460330 C T 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   chr1:3716325:I GCCCTGCACCC G 0.00100708 0 0 0.0039978 0 0 0
>   rs9424299 G A 1.96399 1.72199 1.73801 2 0.850006 0.98703 1.85998
>   rs60615207 A G 0.0509949 0.00698853 0.237 0.0180054 0.0249939 0 0.0339966
>   rs77743432 A C 0.473999 0 0.00100708 0 0 0 0

Comment: You should expand with more detail of how that 'key-variable` behavior is supposed to work..   Tentatively, I'd probably use perl with `split`  to break the columns into arrays, and then compare.  But details?  Fuzzy questions get fuzzy answers

Comment: I've changed it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Edit your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output to remove some of the guesswork. sed and awk are 2 completely different tools, there is no `awk/sed` just as there is no `perl/grep`. This is not a job for sed at all and there's no reason to assume an awk solution would be slower than a perl or python one.

Comment: I've edited the post/question. I've included `head` of file1 and file2, as well as an expected result. I hope this is informative and one can help me instead of putting this question on hold. I understand the question might be to broad, however try to use the principle of charity: imagine you're a biologist with zero education in scripting trying to find a solution for this problem by asking people that are (more) educated in scripting for help. I would think that would go a long way.  @thissuitisblacknot   @andras-deak   @mseifert   @prasun   @mpromonet  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the command-line tool [csvfix](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/).

First you join the two tables together using the first column, then you only choose the rows that you want from the joined rows.

For example, if file1 has 6 columns and file2 has 1,529 columns, the joined rows will have 1,534 fields. (The key-variable isn't repeated.) So if you need the key-variable, columns 2 and 3 from file1, and the other columns from file2, you can specify them like so:

```
csvfix join -f 1:1 file2.csv file1.csv | csvfix order -f 1,1530,1531,4:1529
```

Note that file2.csv is listed first to preserve the order of that file's rows in the output.

If your fields are not delimited by commas, you can pick another separator using the `-sep` option.

Comment: Would this be fast? And do I/we assume that the files are in exactly the same order?

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan It won't be terribly fast because the join step needs to pull both the enormous input files into memory. The order step should be more efficient at streaming the output to a file. Also, it looks like the ordering of the join output is based on the first file, not the second. I edited the answer so the row ordering in the output matches that of file2.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample input and expected output it's just a guess but this may be what you want:

```
$ cat file1
a b c
d e f
g h i

$ cat file2
a 2 3
e 4 5
h 6 7

$ join -o '1.1 2.2 2.3' file2 file1
a b c
```

or maybe:

```
$ join -a 2 file2 file1 | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3
a 2 3
d e f
g h i
```

or:

```
$ join -a 1 file2 file1 | awk '{print $1, $(NF-1), $NF}'
a b c
e 4 5
h 6 7
```

or....

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**   *for clarifications: first columns need match each other; and, the other file is **much** smaller.*

---

Processes line at a time of `file1` and once it runs out copy the rest of `file2`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file1 = 'file1.txt';
my $file2 = 'file2.txt';
my $outfile = 'new_file2.txt';

open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die "Can't open $file1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die "Can't open $file2: $!";
open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;

my ($line1, @ln1, @ln2);
# Need be certain that file2 >= file1 (by number of lines)
while($line1 = <$fh1>) {
    @ln2 = split '\s+', <$fh2>, 4;
    @ln1 = split '\s+', $line1, 4;
    if ($ln1[0] eq $ln2[0]) 
    {
        @ln2[1,2] = @ln1[1,2];
    }
    print $outfh "@ln2";
}

# Copy the rest of file2
while (<$fh2>) { print $outfh }

# Close filehandles if not the end of script
```

Limit `split` to 4 -- the needed fields and the rest of the line. This can be sped up further, but the `file1` is specified to be small, and by a factor of thousand in comparison with `file2`.

Comment: if his file2 was small enough, I considered making a hash array for file2 with the key being the column 1, the contents being columns 2+3,  Then for each line in file 1, uses the `exists` function to see if the key exists in the hash.  If so, replace the column 2-3 members with what is in the hash.  The join aand print the result.   But this approach depends on wheter you can get file2's hash table to fit in memory

Comment: @infixed  It's not small -- OP say 8.3 million rows, and long ones at that.

Comment: Oh,  I was thinking of them backwards.  Even if I refactor my thinking, if  file1 had 8 million rows, it's probably a problem even with only 6 items per row.     Perhaps one of the files can be split to manageable sizes, processed, and then rejoined later.   Flat file fun.

Comment: Thanks @zdim. This was very useful. Almost there. If this questions is not on hold anymore I'll post the answer...

Comment: Thanks @zdim. This was very useful. Almost there. It throws an error at the line where it states `while ($cnt++ < $size2)`. The error is: `Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) `. How do I interpret this? If this questions is not on hold anymore I'll post the answer...

Comment: Also when I write this: `my $size1 = (split '\s+', `wc -l $file1`)[0];
print STDERR "* The size of file1 ($file1) is: $size1.\n";
print STDERR "\n";
my $size2 = (split '\s+', `wc -l $file2`)[0];
print STDERR "* The size of file2 ($file2) is: $file2.\n";`, the output is: `* The size of file1 (file1.txt) is: .

* The size of file2 (file2.txt) is: file2.txt.`. I interpreted $size1 as a counting of lines. Is that not the case?

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan  Updated:  column 1 is compared directly and not to a fixed key (right?), and files are processed differently, `file1` being so much smaller.  Would've helped having this -- post carefully please. Also, there is no need to first get sizes, so external commands are gone.

Answer (score 1):

When run, the following script produces the output shown under the `Output` heading.  So long as file1 does not have too many lines, I think you'll find it quite satisfactory, in that memory requirements basically only depend on the space required to hold the first three columns in file1, and there is no dependence on any sorting:

```
#!/bin/bash

function file1 {
cat<<EOF
a b c
d e f
e x y
g h i
EOF
}

function file2 {
cat<<EOF
a 2 3 many columns one
e 4 5 many columns two
h 6 7 many columns three
EOF
}

awk '
  NR==FNR { 
    if (NF==0) { next }
    col2[$1]=$2; col3[$1]=$3; 
    next
  }
  { if ($1 in col2) { $2=col2[$1]; $3=col3[$1] } }
  { print }      
' <(file1) <(file2)
```

#### Output:

```
a b c many columns one
e x y many columns two
h 6 7 many columns three
```