# Replace and count the occurrences of a specific character in a file (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, str-replace

I am trying to read a source file (for example one in Python) and have each occurrence of a specific character to be replaced with 2 spaces and, also, **count all such replaces**.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/6167676), I use this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(specificChar, '  '), end='')
```

which works exactly as I want (even though it *re-writes every single line*).

But, I **cannot find a way of counting the total number replaces**; I though that trying

```
counter = 0
if is specificChar in line:
    counter += 1
```

*would not be efficient* since I will then be traversing the `line` once for the `counter` and once for the `line.replace` which seems not Pythonic to me.

Is there any other implementation I can consider?

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.subn` which replaces *and* counts, returning a tuple (new_string, number_of_subs_made), like this...

```
import re
count = 0
for line in file:
    (result, qty) = re.subn(specific_char, '  ', line)
    count += qty
    print(result, end='')
```

This is similar to Moses's excellent answer but avoids the double-traversal of each line and is still somewhat readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.count` to count the number of occurrences of the character in the line before replacing:

```
count = 0
for line in file:
     count += line.count(specificChar)
     print(line.replace(specificChar, '  '), end='')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this not traverse the line twice as I mentioned in my description? I am concerned whether or not this not an efficient approach. Or perhaps it is not something too inefficient..?

Comment: This is more readable and faster than counting with a `for` loop *one-by-one* as in your description