# how to Find and replace text with in a file from terminal using vim editor

Tags: python, shell

The file size is more than 40 GB. Want to find some text and replace it.  I will be grateful if I will get some suggestion how to do it.
There are three steps: 1. find space and remove it
 2. find > symbol and replace it with "> ".
3. find < symbol and replace it with " <".

Comment: Grep... since you've tagged this shell.

Comment: One good way to find out how to do it is to search for your exact question and look at the answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed -ie "s/>/\">\"/g" /path/to/file
```

- `-i`: edit in place
- `-e`: run the following command
- `"s/text/replacement/g"`: replace every occurrence of `text` with `replacement`

Comment: Not my downvote... but this seems correct, so why downvote it?