# Replace the text between two lines with new text and keep the rest of the file unchanged

Tags: python

I have the text file (input.txt)

```
*HEADING
*NODE, NSET=ALLNODES
   1,   0.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00
   2,   2.500000e-01,   0.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00
*ELEMENT, TYPE=S9R5, ELSET=EB1
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
 **
 * END OF FILE
```

My goal is replace all the lines between the lines (`*ELEMENT, TYPE=S9R5, ELSET=EB1`) and (`**`) with a new lines.

and keep the rest of the file unchanged. Any solution using: `open('input.txt', 'w') as f1:` would erase everything in the file and write the new two lines and this is not the thing I need.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
text = open("input.txt", "r").read()
with open("input.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        if "line 1" in line:
           line = line.replace("line 1", "line 3")
        elif "line 2" in line:
           line = line.replace("line 2", "line 4")
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

I copied out your `file` into a `file` named `input.txt` and tested the `code` exactly and it gave the right `output` (i.e. changed the `file` in the intended way), so hopefully it works for you too!

Comment: Sorry Joe but I changed the question because I do not know the content of the lines that I need to replace. All that I know is the two lines that I need to replace all the data in between. Thanks