# How to overwrite a specific set of characters from a specific line in python

Tags: python, file, character, overwrite

So, I'm trying to create a program that will automatically edit a specific set of characters in a file (it will read and replace them). No other data can be moved in the file otherwise it might become corrupted so I need to replace the text in the exact same place as before. I have looked around and found nothing useful but here is my code so far:

```
l = 3
w = 0
with open("InidCrd000.crd") as myfile:
    hexWord = myfile.readlines()[l].split()[w]
    codeA = hexWord[58]
    codeB = hexWord[59]
    print("Current value: ", codeA, codeB)
    codeA = " "
    codeB = "Ð"
    print("New value: ", codeA, codeB)
```

**EDIT** - I now have this code (credit - Ilayaraja), which works but then it breaks the file up into lines and places random data in incorrect positions (although the inputted data is in the correct position):

```
def replace(filepath, lineno, position, newchar):
    with open(filepath, "r") as reader:
        lines = reader.readlines()
        l = lines[lineno-1]
        l = l[0:position] + newchar + l[position+1:]
        lines[lineno-1] = l
    with open(filepath, "w") as writer:
        writer.writelines(lines)
replace("InidCrd000.crd", 4, 57, "")
replace("InidCrd000.crd", 4, 58, "Ð")
```

If you want the file for testing, here it is: [1drv.ms/u/s!AqRsP9xMA0g1iqMl-ZQbXUqX2WY8aA](http://1drv.ms/u/s!AqRsP9xMA0g1iqMl-ZQbXUqX2WY8aA) (It's a onedrive file)

Comment: Can you show a snippet from the input file?

Comment: Here's a small snippet (the file is usually edited through hex but I'm writing this program to help people who can't hex edit):   aÐP°À
€                                    ‚i‚c‚q‚X‚X          Ð  T! ÿÿÿÿ

Comment: The bit that get's replaced is the  " Ð" part (I know I'm overwriting it with itself but in other files it will be a different value)

Comment: @Ricochet1136 If it is a binary file then open it as binary and replace bytes instead of characters.

Comment: Good idea but I still need to figure out how to overwrite a specific position on a specific line

Answer (score 0):

first find the code you want to change using this :

```
l = 3
w = 0
with open("InidCrd000.crd") as myfile:
    hexWord = myfile.readlines()[l].split()[w]
    codeA = hexWord[58]
    codeB = hexWord[59]
myfile.close()
```

then change like this :

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
         line.replace(codeA, textToReplace)
```

Comment: So for the textToReplace do I just put the characters I want to replace?

Comment: exactly .. and that fileToSearch your file name

Comment: I tried the code but all it seems to do is completely blank out the file.

Comment: then take look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Define a function with the arguments the path of the file(`filepath`), line number(`lineno` 1 to N), position of the character in the line(`position` 0 to N) and the new character to be overwritten(`newchar`) as follows:

```
def replace(filepath, lineno, position, newchar):
    with open(filepath, "r") as reader:
        lines = reader.readlines()
        l = lines[lineno-1]
        l = l[0:position] + newchar + l[position+1:]
        lines[lineno-1] = l
    with open(filepath, "w") as writer:
        writer.writelines(lines)
```

You can call the function as follows to replace the characters:

```
replace("InidCrd000.crd", 3, 58, " ")
replace("InidCrd000.crd", 3, 59, "Ð")
```

Comment: The code worked but it has moved all the characters, so now the replaced text has moved from CD-CE to C8-C9. This is because python has broken up the file into different segments from what it originally was.

Comment: Here's the stock file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqRsP9xMA0g1iqMl-ZQbXUqX2WY8aA (It's a onedrive file)

Comment: @Ricochet1136 It is not accessible.

Comment: Not defaultly because that's how it's supposed to be but it can be viewed in notepad (HxD can also be used to view the hex)