# replace multiple words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace words as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240862/find-and-replace-multiple-words-in-a-file-python) but for a column in a dataframe. I also want to keep the original column and other columns in the dataframe.

```
a = ["isn't", "can't"]
b = ["is not", "cannot"]

for line in df['text']:
    for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
        line = line.replace(a1, b1)
    df['text1'].write(line)
```

`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series`

Input dataframe

```
ID    text      
1     isn't bad
2     can't play
```

Output

```
ID    text          text1
1     isn't bad     is not bad
2     can't play    cannot play
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Likely you can do this with `str.replace` or just `.replace`, but we really would need a minimum reproducible example with copy/pastable sample input data as well as expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @DavidErickson: I have modified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two lists `a` and `b`, then this would be the best way to `.replace` the values by passing `regex=True`:

```
a = ["isn't", "can't"]
b = ["is not", "cannot"]
# df=pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')
df['text1'] = df['text'].replace(a,b,regex=True)
df
Out[68]: 
   ID        text        text1
0   1   isn't bad   is not bad
1   2  can't play  cannot play
```

Please note that `a` and `b` should be the same length. If it is just a small list, this technique is fine, but if it is a larger list, you would probably want to build a dictionary.

Comment: Some words are not replaced. I am not sure what happened

Comment: I find out. It is due to the font difference.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `apply` method on dataframe column in conjuction with `lambda` function you can acheive that, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
a = ["isn't", "can't"]
b = ['is not', 'cannot']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'text': ["isn't bad", "can't play"]})
df['a'], df['b'] = a,b
print(df.head())
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   id        text      a       b
0   1   isn't bad  isn't  is not
1   2  can't play  can't  cannot
```

You can now do `apply` on this dataframe like this:

```
df['vals'] = pd.Series(map(lambda x,y,z: x.replace(y, z), list(df.text), list(df.a), list(df.b)))
print(df.head())
```

Final output:

```
   id        text      a       b         vals
0   1   isn't bad  isn't  is not   is not bad
1   2  can't play  can't  cannot  cannot play
```

You can consider `vals` column for your analysis or extract only the required columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a lookup table to change your words;

import pandas as pd

```
dict = {
    'text':["isn't bad", "can't play"]
}
table = {
    "isn't":"is not",
    "can't":"cannot"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
revised_text = []
for text in dict['text']:
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in table.keys():
            revised_text.append(text.replace(word, table[word]))

df['text1'] = revised_text
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option.

```
df['text1'] = df['text']
for i in range(len(a)):
    df['text1'] = df['text1'].str.replace(a[i],b[i])
```

Here is another way which does not involve iterating.

```
replacedict = {"isn't":"is not",
          "can't":"cannot"}
text = df['text']
df = df.assign(text=df['text'].str.split(' ')).explode('text').replace(replacedict).groupby('id').agg({'text':lambda x: ' '.join(x)}).reset_index()
df['text1'] = df['text']
df['text'] = text
```