# How do I replace a text file using regex package in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am finding patterns within a large text file, then I remove the patterns, and print the text. But, I am trying to replace the old text within the file (with the patterns) with the `new_text` without the patterns.

Im using the regex package, and no matter what i try it doesnt work

My command `.replace` is not working.

```
import re

rgx_list = ['Read More',
            'Read',
            'And follow us on Twitter to keep up with the latest news and and acute and primary Care.',...]

txt_path = '/Users/sofia/Documents/src/fakenews1/data/news-data/war_sc_r.txt'

with open(txt_path) as new_txt_file:
    new_text = new_txt_file.read()

for rgx_match in rgx_list:
        new_text = re.sub(rgx_match, '', new_text)

new_text.replace(txt_path, new_text)

print(new_text)
```

Thank you !

Comment: `with open(txt_path) as new_txt_file:` automatically opens the file in read mode. You're not writing anything back to the file. There are plenty of tutorials and questions/answers on reading and writing files.

Comment: Ive read every forum on stack overflow. nothing is helping me

Comment: `replace` doesn't edit the string; it returns a new string. Strings are immutable.   It looks like you think it replaces the file path content.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are using `replace()` function. Maybe read up on the documentation for [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). If you want to write the `new_text` to your file, you should open the file again in `write` mode then write the new content to the file.

```
import re

rgx_list = ['Read More',
            'Read',
            'And follow us on Twitter to keep up with the latest news and and acute and primary Care.']

txt_path = 'newyorktimes_test.txt'

with open(txt_path) as new_txt_file:
    new_text = new_txt_file.read()

for rgx_match in rgx_list:
        new_text = re.sub(rgx_match, '', new_text)

with open(txt_path, 'w') as new_txt_file:
  new_txt_file.write(new_text)
```

If you are looking for a more [in place editing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/7570485) approach, there are libraries to help you just a Google search away.