# Editing a line of text file after a word

Tags: python, text, replace, line, edit

I have a properties file and have to edit it through python. I need to edit the line `jmx.admin.pwd=SomeRandomPassword` and replace the random password with my own password. I am unable to do so.

The text file looks like this:

```
some line
some line
some line
min.pop.password=SomeRandomNumbersWordsCharacters
some line
some line
some line
```

Below should be the modified output:

```
some line
some line
some line
min.pop.password=My_Password
some line
some line
some line
```

Any help is highly appreciated as I am new in Python.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried in python so far ? show us your effort, and where it goes wrong. Give as much informaiton about your code as possible. Also update the question with the actual output of your code.

Comment: General Algo...iterate your text file line by line and match "min.pop.password". When the condition matches replace it with the string you want

Comment: So you should show what have you tried so far. This previous questions may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, first open the file, then read all the lines into a list `content` removing `\n` from each as you do so.  From here you can search this list for your `target` which has the word or some unique phrase in it, for this we used `password`. No we can set that to `target` while splitting it at the `=`, and also store the `target_idx`.  From here we just alter the second index of `target` that we `.split('=')` and then `.join()` that back together.  Now we can assign our new line `phrase` to the `target_idx` of `content` replacing the old `target`.  After we can open our `text.txt` back up and write the new `content` using `'\n'.join(content)`

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    content = [line.strip() for line in f]

for i in content:
    if 'password' in i:
        target = i.split('=')
        target_idx = content.index(i)

target[-1] = 'My_Password'
mod = '='.join(target)

content[target_idx] = mod

with open('text1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(content))
```

Before

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/10.3$ cat text.txt 
> some line
> some line
> some line
> min.pop.password=SomeRandomNumbersWordsCharacters
> some line
> some line
> some line
> ```

After

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/10.3$ cat text.txt 
> some line
> some line
> some line
> min.pop.password=My_Password
> some line
> some line
> some line
> ```