# python: I want to search a line and replace a line

Tags: python

I want to search a line and replace a line in a file.txt,

```
CURRENT_BUILD = 111111
```

with

```
CURRENT_BUILD = 221111
```

Using Python.

Comment: please show what did you try and what troubles do you have.

Comment: Is CURRENT_BUILD = 111111 in your txt file

Comment: Show `file.txt` file content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the lines in the file, saving them to a `list` and then output the list back to the file, line by line, replacing the line if necessary:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line == 'CURRENT_BUILD = 111111\n':
            f.write('CURRENT_BUILD = 221111\n')
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: small change replace line starting with CURRENT_BUILD =  with  CURRENT_BUILD =555555

Answer (score 0):

```
CURRENT_BUILD = '111111'
print (CURRENT_BUILD.replace('111111', '221111'))
```

The syntax of replace() is:

```
str.replace(old, new [, count])
```

old - old substring you want to replace

new - new substring which would replace the old substring

count (optional) - the number of times you want to replace the old substring with the new substring

If count is not specified, replace() method replaces all occurrences of the old substring with the new substring.

I'm not sure if this is what you meant as you are unclear and haven't shown what the .txt file is but this is replace anyways.

**EDIT**

if it is in text replace you want then this would be your best bet.

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
for line in file:
    print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

credit to @jfs from this post [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python)