# replacing a special string in a file without removing the other contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

```
with open ('npt.mdp','r+') as npt:
    if 'Water_and_ions' in npt.read():
        print(" I am replacing water and Ions...with only Water")
        s=npt.read()
        s= s.replace('Protein_BSS Water_and_ions', 'Protein_BSS Water')
        with open ('npt.mdp',"w") as f:
            f.write(s)
```

Text I want to replace is not being replaced. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dupe for what you want to do: [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python)

**Here is why *your* approach did not work:**

You consume your filestream by checking `if 'Water_and_ions' in npt.read():` - afterwards the `s=npt.read()` can not read anything anymore because the stream is at its end.

Fix:

```
with open ('npt.mdp','r+') as npt:
    s = npt.read()                       # read here
    if 'Water_and_ions' in s:            # test s
        print(" I am replacing water and Ions...with only Water")

        s = s.replace('Protein_BSS Water_and_ions', 'Protein_BSS Water')
        with open ('npt.mdp',"w") as f:
            f.write(s)
```

Instead of reading the file into a variable you could also `seek(0)` back to the files start - but if you want to modify it anyway, the options in the dupe are better suited to work for archieving your goal.