# How to add quotes(' ') to words in a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file with a punch of keywords:
`baseball,player,bat,creek,home,guy,squatting,plane`, something like this and I want a code to change them to be like this:
`'baseball','player','bat','creek','home','guy','squatting','plane'`.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv 
file = pd.read_csv('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/error_score-updated.csv') 
out = open('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/keywords.txt', 'w') 
for i in range(len(file)): 
    out.writelines(file['words'][i] + ',')
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search and replace text in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file)

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: import pandas as pd
import csv

file = pd.read_csv('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/error_score-updated.csv')
out = open('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/keywords.txt', 'w')

for i in range(len(file)):
    out.writelines(file['words'][i] + ','). Here is my code so far

Comment: @roganjosh I think he does want to add the quotation marks.

Comment: Found the solution:

import pandas as pd
import csv

file = pd.read_csv('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/error_score-updated.csv')
out = open('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/keywords.txt', 'w')

for i in range(len(file)):
    out.writelines("'%s'" %file['words'][i] + ',')

Answer (score 0):

**This is only for comma delimited csvs.**

This is a **janky** solution but it solves your problem:
(I do this just by reading the raw file - it'll only do one line but it literally would be a 20 second change... the only reason I haven't changed that was because you didn't provide a good example of what you wanted to do)
I'm sure you could find the 'proper' answer with one minute of research.

```
file = open('error_score-updated.csv', 'r+') 
out = open('keywords.txt', 'w+') 
output_string = ""
for cells in file:
    for word in cells.split(','):
        output_string += ("'{}', ".format(word))

out.write(output_string[:-2])
```

Comment: Thank you ... I have tried a bunch things but didn't work. but thank you again. What I need is to change the format of word cat to 'cat', .

Comment: That will do that for the top row. If it's already outputted into a text file this should solve your problem as well. Can you give an example of the exact file you want to change from and to?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have found that works:

file = pd.read_csv('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/error_score-updated.csv')
out = open('/home/greshad/code/data_vis/keywords.txt', 'w')

for i in range(len(file)):
    out.writelines("'%s'" %file['words'][i] + ',')

Answer (score 0):

Or just for fun (only for fun / vintage):

```
def MrKeys(keyList):
  val = []
  for x in keyList: val.append(x) if x!=',' else val.append(' ')
  val_srt = str(val)
  return val_srt.replace(", ","").replace("'' ''",",").replace("''","").replace(",","','")
```

And call it, ex: >>> print (MrKeys(words))

Or if the txt file is all likes "baseball,player,bat,creek,home,guy,squatting,plane"
try with:

> > > print (('\'')+word_list.replace(",","','")+('\''))