# How to read dictionary key:value from json file, search the key in a text file and replace the key value through python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file: oracle.json

```
{"Oracle_installation": [{"ORACLE_HOSTNAME": "paulsusm.xxx.com"}]}
```

Now, I had to read the JSON file values in my test.py file:

```
import json
with open('D:\oracle.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

hostname = data['Oracle_installation'][0]['ORACLE_HOSTNAME']
print(hostname)
```

In the JSON file, the key:value pair is: `(ORACLE_HOSTNAME, paulsusm.xxx.com)`. I need to change the `ORACLE_HOSTNAME` value in another file `db.rsp`. My python code is supposed to search the `"ORACLE_HOSTNAME"` word in `db.rsp` file and change the value, which is stored in `'hostname'` variable in python. How can I do this in python?

Comment: what is db.rsp file content ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141572/5316326), which in your case would be:

```py
filename = 'db.rsp'
# Read in the file
with open(filename, 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace("ORACLE_HOSTNAME", hostname)

# Write the file out again
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

### solution 2

And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/5316326) you can use `fileinput`, which already supports inplace editing. In your case this code will look like:

```py
import fileinput

filename = 'db.rsp'
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace("ORACLE_HOSTNAME", hostname), end='')
```