# Modify mule XML file with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, xml, mule

Im working on a simple automation python3 script to modify some of my xml file on a mule4 projects, and based on input I want to add global elements, I found some cool things to do by using element tree, but im having a blocker where I cannot add multiple attributes, as a sample, I have:

```
<mule>
  some_code
</mule>
```

and I want to add this element as a new child element inside the tag 'mule':

```
<mule>
some_code
<http:listener-config name="HTTPS_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:description="Secure HTTPS listener global config">
    <http:listener-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="${https.host}" port="${https.port}" tlsContext="TLS_Context" />
</http:listener-config>
</mule>
```

So.. I don't have much actual code beside the one I have been testing/playing with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse("./src/main/mule/global.xml")

root_node = doc.getroot()

child = ET.SubElement(root_node, "http:listener-config")

child.set("name","HTTPS_Listener_config")

connection  = ET.SubElement(child,"http:listener-connection")

connection.text =  "protocol=HTTPS"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root_node)

tree.write("./src/main/mule/global.xml")
```

This is the result... not quite there yet... plus thar 'ns#:' on the tags..

```
...
<http:listener-config name="HTTPS_Listener_config"><http:listener-connection>protocol=HTTPS</http:listener-connection></http:listener-config></ns0:mule>
```

any pointers on simple example will help me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to use python XML functions you need to set all the right namespace configurations right.

Though it is more error prone you might want to just [replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876912/721855). For example replacing the end tag `</mule>` by a multi line string. Something like this:

```
f = open(filein,'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

myconfig="""   <http:listener-config name="HTTPS_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:description="Secure HTTPS listener global config">
    <http:listener-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="${https.host}" port="${https.port}" tlsContext="TLS_Context" />
</http:listener-config>
</mule>
"""
newdata = filedata.replace("</mule>",myconfig)

f = open(fileout,'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```