# Csv, Python, separating elements in one column to different columns

Tags: python, csv

So I have a CSV file like this,

[image]

how can I separate them into different columns like this,

[image]

using python without using the pandas lib.

Comment: I suggest taking look at [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) built-in module

Comment: They're already separated into different columns, you should import the file as CSV in your Excel and specify comma (`,`) as the separator

Comment: the problem is they are located in column A

Comment: @bernardo, you can import the file as CSV and change the column delimiter to `,`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation that should work in python 3.6+.

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as inputfile:
    with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as outputfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)  # reader
        fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)  # writer
        # make header
        writer.writeheader()
        # loop over each row in input CSV
        for row in reader:
            # get first column
            column: str = str(row[fieldnames[0]])
            numbers: list = column.split(",")
            if len(numbers) != len(fieldnames):
                print("Error: Lengths not equal")

            # write row in output CSV
            writer.writerow({field: num for field, num in zip(fieldnames, numbers)})
```

**Explanation of the code**:

- The above code takes two file names `input.csv` and `output.csv`. The names being verbose don't need any further explanation.
- It reads each row from `input.csv` and writes corresponding row in `output.csv`.
- The last line is a "dictionary comprehension" combined with `zip` (similar to "list comprehensions" for lists). It's a nice way to do a lot of stuff in a single line but same code in expanded form looks like:

```py
row = {}
for field, num in zip(fieldnames, numbers):
   row[field] = num
writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already separated into different columns by `,` as separator, but the european version of excel usually uses `;` as separator. You can specify the separator, when you import the csv:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

If you really want to change the file content with python use the replace function and replace `,` with `;`: [How to search and replace text in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file)