# Replace a line in a text file using python

Tags: python

I want to replace some of the contents of my file. I have this code:

```
username= input("enter your new username")
password= input("enter the new password")

file = open("testfile.txt", "r")
replaced_content = ""
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    new_line = line.replace("username:", "username: " + username)
    replaced_content = replaced_content + new_line + "\n"

file.close()
write_file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
write_file.write(replaced_content)
write_file.close()
```

Here, `testfile.txt` contains:

```
username:
password:
```

The problem is when I input the replacement text, it's being added rather than replaced. For example, when I enter a username, I want to replace the line "username:" by "username: admin"; but when I run the code repeatedly, it gets added repeatedly, thus:

```
username: admin admin
password:
```

If my username is already in the text file I want to replace it with an other one and not adding the new to the other. How can I make this work? (I try to not import packages or other things like that in my code.)

Comment: "I try to not import packages or other thing like that in my script" Why? The standard library exists for a reason.

Comment: "The problem is when I enter what I want to replace with, it's adding it not replacing." Well, yes, that's what your code says to do. `line.replace("username:", "username: " + username)`. It looks for the `"username:"` text and then creates *the result of adding the name to that* and does the replacement. Of course it will put the `"username:"` back in. It seems that the `"username:"` text *isn't actually what you want to replace, but instead *the rest of the line after it*, right? It is only possible to solve programming problems when you *clearly understand what you want to do*.

Comment: I edited the question to ask the actual question more clearly, fix some minor grammatical issues, and remove off-topic commentary. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum and thus [we just want the question, not any social niceties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search and replace text in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the line equal "username:" and only do the replacement then.  In this code it will replace the `username:` in a line `"username: admin"` with `"username: " + username` giving you the extra admin at the end

Comment: By the way check out the fileinput module that comes with python which is a handy way of processing files and can do in place filtering

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you find a "username:" in the line and replace it with "username: " + username. So if you had a line like "username: admin", it would simply replace the username as asked, and it would become "username: admin admin".

Try changing the

```
new_line = line.replace("username:", "username: " + username)
```

to

```
new_line = "username: " + username if line.count("username:") > 0 else line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested, please report of any errors found)v

```
username= input("enter your new username")
password= input("enter the new password")
new_l=[username, password]

write_file = open("testfile.txt", "r+")
lines=write_file.readlines()

for i,j in zip(lines, new_l):
        write_file.write(i.strip('\n')+j)
        write_file.write('\n')
write_file.close()
```