# How do I separate SQL column values which are separated by <SOH> to be separate columns in Python3?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, xml, csv

**CSV File:**

No Headers

```
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=70<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=237 ----This entire message is FIXData value
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=71<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=238
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=72<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=239
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=73<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=240
```

Code Snippet of how I get the data into a CSV file from querying MS DB.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=abc;UID=user;PWD=password')

sql = """select FIXData from table WHERE MessageTimestamp BETWEEN '2021-09-20 07:00:00' AND '2021-09-20 07:01:00';"""

 

rows = cursor.execute(sql)

 

with open(r'HOME/sqlresults.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

#    writer.writerow([x[0] for x in cursor.description]) --- dont want headers

    for row in rows:

        writer.writerow(row)
```

**Issue:**

- As can be seen from the CSV file, the entire FIX message is squished into 1 cell (thinking Excel here).
- The FIX message is separated by , and basically I want to separate the tags into separate cells.

**Desired Output:**

- CSV file format (ideally separated by ';') so that when I open the csv in excel, the tag values will be in there own cell and not compressed in one.

```
8=Fix1.1;9=70;35=AE;10=237
8=Fix1.1;9=71;35=AE;10=238
8=Fix1.1;9=72;35=AE;10=239
8=Fix1.1;9=73;35=AE;10=240
```

**Bonus Desired Output:**

- This is optional, but if can be done within the above would be helpful.
- Remove the first part of tag

**CSV File**

```
Fix1.1;70;AE;237
Fix1.1;71;AE;238
Fix1.1;72;AE;239
Fix1.1;73;AE;240
```

**Note:**

- Please note I cannot use third party modules (Pandas dataframe not to be used etc)

Comment: I would urge you to fix your data structure. You are violating 1NF which is why this such a challenge. If that isn't feasible then I would suggest doing this in your query. It is fairly easy with a decent split function. There is a built in splitter in the newer versions but it somewhat limited because they failed to provide the rank in the output which is borderline criminal.

Comment: Agree on the 1NF is that means why they couldn't dump the message into separate rows/columns. Unfortunately, not much I can argue, given Networks team dumps messages into the DB as so. Would you be able to elaborate on the split function please? I'm given a read only account so cannot modify table etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I figured I will just use the Python replace method to convert the SOH character to `,` which gives me the above desired output.

I managed to get a solution using the thread,  [How to search and replace text in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file)

```
# Read in the file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('x01', ',') ---- Using RHEL based system so found '\u001' didnt work for me. Dont know the details of why....

# Write the file out again
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```