# Python pass variable to html file

Tags: python, html

I have a python file called `writer.py` and an `index.html` in the same directory.

In my python file i have following import:

```py
from reader import titles, links
print("titles and links")
for i in range(min(len(titles), 10)):
    print("- {} ({})".format(titles[i], links[i]))
```

i now want to display a the first title of my array *titles* in my `index.html` file, which currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a Framework or something to render your HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

First you load filecontent of index.html. Then you replace `{{ title }}` with the title in list at index 0. After that you write the new filecontent back to the file.

```
from reader import titles, links
print("titles and links")
for i in range(min(len(titles), 10)):
    print("- {} ({})".format(titles[i], links[i]))

# Read in the file
with open('index.html', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('{{ title }}', titles[0])

# Write the file out again
with open('index.html', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141572/8980073

Note: All occurrences of the specified phrase will be replaced, if nothing else is specified.
But you can change this behavior, see [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) `string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)`. So you could write `filedata.replace('{{ title }}', titles[0], 1)` for replacing only first occurrence.

Comment: Next time you try to set a different title, this will fail, as there is nothing left to replace...

Comment: If this is important to the user, of course you can use htmlparser http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html or replace the `str.replace()` with regex like `filedata = re.sub('<h1>(.*?)</h1>', '<h1>' + titles[0] +'</h1>', filedata)` then you have to use `import re` in the beginning.

Comment: Maybe to solve this issue, you could read the first file as a template (having the file in a different folder: `with open('templates/index.html', 'r') as file :`) and still write to same `index.html`