# Python argv file, edit, then write new file

Tags: python

Using Python, if I want to

A. read a text file in using argv
 B. make string substitutions (search & replace)
 C. write out a new file with a new name

Can I do that with just one open() function? Here's what I have so far, and yeah, I know it's not going to run as is.

```
import sys, re

FarmFixer, farmfile = argv

print "What is the serial number of the site?",
_nnn = raw_input()

print "What is the brand, or product name?",
_brand = raw_input()

print "What is the (fqdn) ServerName?",
_server_name = raw_input()

print "What is the content path?",
_content_path = raw_input()

print "What is the DAM path?",
_dampath = raw_input()

print "Which environment is this for?",
_env = raw_input()

print "What is the cache document root?",
_cache_docroot = raw_input()

for line in file_open:
   re.sub("NNN", "_nnn", line)
   re.sub("BRAND", "_brand", line)
   re.sub("CONTENT_PATH", "_content_path", line)
   re.sub("DAMPATH", "_dampath", line)
   re.sub("ENV", "_env", line)
   re.sub("CACHE_DOCROOT", "_cache_docroot", line)

farmfile = _nnn + _brand + "farm.any"
outie = open(farmfile, 'w')
outie.close
print farmfile
```

Of course the re.sub lines fail utterly.

Comment: Never mind the broken re.sub lines for now.

Comment: Recommendation: use a `with` statement to handle closing the file. It is safer in the event of errors, and simpler to code. The code you posted does not call the close method.

Comment: `outie.close` does not close a file. `outie.close()` does.

Answer (score 2):

You say you have two files, one you will read and a new one you want to write.  You will need to open each file.

This question is essentially the same as this older question: [edit text file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1582750/1172714).  You need to open the one file, read it, open the other file, and write to it.

Comment: Yes, that was me. I still haven't learned much Python.

Thanks.

Comment: @dsh, how did you know the OP asked that question considering it was 6 years ago?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham When I saw a second "farmfile" question today, I checked his profile before responding so that I could formulate an appropriate response. That question was at the top of the list because it is his top-voted question, and also the source of his gold badge. I then kept this answer brief since that once already has more detailed explanation and examples.