# How to add xml-stylesheet tag to XML file using python?

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I'm trying to add the xml-stylesheet tag in front of an existing XML file using python.

Eg. I'm trying to add

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="audit_stylesheet.xsl" ?>
```

to the beginning of my XML file.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your line to

```
"<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"audit_stylesheet.xsl\" ?>"
```

and use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917395/4843078 you should be good to go