# Append text to the last line of file with python

Tags: python, bash, shell

First, I use `echo 'hello,' >> a.txt` to create a new file with one line looks like that. And I know `\n` is at the last of the line.

[image]

Then I get some data from python, for example "world", I wish to append "world" at the first line, so I use the python code below:

```
f = open('a.txt','a')
f.write("world\n")
f.flush()
f.close()
```

And, here is the result. I know the start point for python to write is at the next line, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: But you do not have to write a new line with echo. You can use `echo -n 'hello,'` to omit that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepend line to beginning of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: OMG! You gave me inspiration. Actually, I use `echo` to create a new line and then use `sed` to append another data at this line, and then use Python to append another data. So now, I can always use `echo -n` to append data in bash and finally use python to append another data, that's right?@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: You can't append data before the end of the old file contents with a file opened in an append mode, you need `'r+'`. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/4014959

Comment: please replace the pictures by text

Comment: Pretend that you have never heard of `echo`, and use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is using echo with -n an option when you're creating a.txt first time

echo -n 'hello,' >> a.txt

Otherwise read file first in a list ,use strip(\n) with each element while reading and then rewrite the file before appending more text

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite the previous file contents you need to open it in `'r+'` mode, as explained in [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/4014959). And to be able to seek to arbitrary positions in the file you need to open it in binary mode. Here's a short demo.

**qtest.py**

```py
with open('a.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    # Move pointer to the last char of the file
    f.seek(-1, 2)
    f.write(' world!\n'.encode())
```

**test**

```bash
$ echo 'hello,' >a.txt
$ hd a.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 0a                              |hello,.|
00000007
$ ./qtest.py
$ hd a.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77  6f 72 6c 64 21 0a        |hello, world!.|
0000000e
```