# Adding a title to a dataframe when writing it in csv using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to add a title to a dataframe when I write it into csv. My problems is that I am not managing to add the title above the dataframe.

I followed the advice in this link ([How to add blank rows before a data frame while using pandas.to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372868/how-to-add-blank-rows-before-a-data-frame-while-using-pandas-to-csv/66965621#66965621)) and add the title before the to_csv part but it's giving me the same result.

My code is:

```
tables = [table_bin_fill_temp_regime, table_velocity_temp_regime, table_count_temp_regime,
          table_bin_fill_chill_preference, table_velocity_chill_preference, table_count_chill_preference]

table_names = ["Average Bin_fill per temperature regime per Pareto bucket",
               "Average Velocity per temperature regime per Pareto bucket",
               "Average number or skus per temperature regime per Pareto bucket"]

for table in tables:
    for table_name in table_names:
        with open(path, 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(table_name)
            outfile.write('\n')
            table.to_csv(path, mode="a",header=["Bucket 20%","Bucket 40%","Bucket 60%","Bucket 80%","Bucket 100%",], line_terminator='\n')
            outfile.write('\n')
```

And what I get is:

```
temp_regime Bucket 20% Bucket 40% Bucket 60% Bucket 80% Bucket 100% 

AMBIENT     0.012320481 0.004642788 0.002300375 0.001441901 0.000746188 

CHILLED     0.056461032 0.01953134 0.008969644 0.004854571 0.001559037 

Average Bin_fill per temperature regime per Pareto bucket
```

I am aiming for:

```
Average Bin_fill per temperature regime per Pareto bucket

temp_regime Bucket 20% Bucket 40% Bucket 60% Bucket 80% Bucket 100% 

AMBIENT     0.012320481 0.004642788 0.002300375 0.001441901 0.000746188 

CHILLED     0.056461032 0.01953134 0.008969644 0.004854571 0.001559037
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `path` to `outfile` in your `table.to_csv()` and see how it works. Namely,

```
table.to_csv(outfile, mode="a",header=["Bucket 20%","Bucket 40%","Bucket 60%","Bucket 80%","Bucket 100%",], line_terminator='\n')
```

Comment: Yyyyyyyeeeees! Thanks!