# How to write/append a result from program with existing file at other directory with same name?

Tags: python, bash, pandas, file, file-processing

I wanted to write a result getting from code, to same name existing file in other directory "/home/work/new_data/ " at first line. My file names are abc.1 to abc.1000

I tried as following but I didn't get output as expected, is it due to myfile contains "." character or something else I was missing? (my file is little bigger)

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re
    import glob

    for filename in sorted(glob.glob('abc.*')):
     with open(filename) as f:
     df = pd.read_table(f, sep=" ", skiprows=2, names = ["Name" , "price", "quntity", "avg_q", "kke", "te"])

     mean = np.mean(df.price)

     name = (re.sub('[^0-9]','' , filename)) . #extracting the number from filename

    #NOW I TRIED FOLLOWING TO write mean at first line of existing file

    with open ("/home/work/new_data/abc.(name)", "rw") as new:
         lines = new.readlines() # read old content
         new.seek(0) # go back to the beginning of the file
         new.write('{}'.format(mean)) # write new content at the beginning
         for line in lines: # write old content after new
              new.write(line)
         new.close()
```

I want abc.1 to be

```
      mean    #got from program output
      title
      date
      soap 10 1000 56 3 7
      sheets 34 2000 34 2 8
      ...
```

My actual file which I was processing abc.1:

```
      title
      date
      soap 10 1000 56 3 7
      sheets 34 2000 34 2 8
      ...
```

I refer [Prepend line to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file) still problem doesn't solved.

Comment: I think you may want to open the file with mode 'r+'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepend line to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: Sir, I use code from that example still problem wasn't solved, so I put again here. Otherwise why should I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code snippet and its worked for me.

```
>>> with open("testfile","r+") as f:
...     lines = f.read()
...     f.seek(0)
...     f.write("back to line number 1 ")
...     f.write(lines)
...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [1]: file_name = "abc.txt"
   ...: open(file_name, "w").write("title\ndate\nsoap 10 1000 56 3 7\nsheets 34 2000 34 2 8\n")
   ...: 
   ...: !cat $file_name
title
date
soap 10 1000 56 3 7
sheets 34 2000 34 2 8

In [2]: f = open(file_name, "r").read().splitlines()
   ...: mean = 44
   ...: open(file_name, "w").write('\n'.join(['mean  ' + str(mean)]+f))
   ...: !cat $file_name
mean  44
title
date
soap 10 1000 56 3 7
sheets 34 2000 34 2 8
```

Comment: It helps if you add some description of how you solved the problem and what was the problem in the code of the poster.