# How to append to file rather than create a new file with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to append some text to the beginning of a file in python, however rather than appending text to the file, it creates a new file with the same name, and writes to that file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
files = 'f0_ascii'
x = 0
for file in os.listdir(files):
    x += 1
    with open(file, 'a') as file2:
        y = 0
        for line in file:
            y += 1
        file2.seek(0, 0)
        string_in_string = "sometext {}".format(y - 10)
        file2.write(string_in_string)
        file2.close()
        if x == 1:
            exit()
```

I want it to append the beginning of the existing file with `"sometext {}".format(y-10)`

Comment: Related: [Prepend line to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: Can I ask why do you open your file in a loop? What does your script do?

Comment: I want to do the same thing to all the files in the folder 'f0_ascii', so the intention is that it opens the first file, appends it, then the second and so on

Comment: When you open a file in `append` mode, it tries to *append* the data, which means add it at the end. But then your code does a `seek()` to the beginning of the file. After that what you write to that file will overwrite what was there before. There isn't a `prepend` mode. You can't easily do what you want with a textfile because they are not really designed for random access.

Comment: Next question. Why do you need that x? You just exit after first iteration.

Comment: Because the code doesn't currently work so there's no point doing it for more than one file

Comment: @BoarGules ah that's where I was going wrong, I changed it so that it reads the file, and saves the content, then creates a new file which prints the new information, then the contents of the original

Answer (score 0):

It works if the folder directory is specified:

```
import os
files = 'my_folder'


def line_prepender(filename, line):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.write(line.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + content)


for file in os.listdir(files):

    y = 0
    for line in file:
        y += 1
    line_prepender(r'my_folder\{}'.format(file), "sometext {}".format(y - 10))
```

If it's not specified, `open()` just can't find your files in the current directory, so it just creates and opens them there.

EDIT: Used some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file) to make this script do exactly what you want.

Comment: I think the problem actually has to do with how appending to a file automatically occurs at the end, as boargules said in the comments. And I solved this problem by running the code from the directory