# How can I prepend to the top of the file?

Tags: python-3.x

I looked through all over, but could not find a good simple code that allows me to prepend a string to an existing file.

The file is this:

```
brave
charlie
delta
echo
```

I want to prepend "alpha" to the file so it'll look like this:

```
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
```

What is the best way to go about this?
What I have tried so far is this:

```
with open('file', 'rb+') as fp:
     fp.seek(0)
     fp.write('alpha)
```

but this overwrites the first line

Comment: check [Prepend line to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prepend something you have to read from the file first.

```
with open('tmpFile.txt', 'rb+') as fp:
  file_text = fp.read()
  fp.seek(0)
  fp.write(b'alpha\n' + file_text)


original file contents:
brave
charlie
delta
echo

file contents after write:
alpha
brave
charlie
delta
echo
```