# Add a line of code in multiples python files

Tags: python, macos

I have to add `from constants import MY_CONSTANT` to 100 python files.

Is there a simple and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Write a Python script to loop the files and add the line :)

Comment: You can regex replace those files: `(^)` with `$1from constants import MY_CONSTANT` but why?

Comment: This is a terrifying question. Why do you even have one hundred files that need to share a constant with a generic name? This should be a warning sign that you have left the path of righteousness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepend line to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: How do you plan to either 1) Remove the *current* definition of `MY_CONSTANT` or 2) start to *use* `MY_CONSTANT` in each file? You may as well add the line by hand while addressing this issue.

Comment: `for f in *.py; do new=${f}_new ; echo 'import foo from bar' >  $FILENAME; less $f >> $FILENAME; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just treat python files like any other text files and write to them. Assuming they are all in the same folder (if not just adapt the loop to go through the relevant folders):

```
for file in os.listdir(folderpath):   
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        with open(file,'r+') as f:
            content = f.read()
            f.seek(0, 0)
            f.write('from constants import MY_CONSTANT' + '\n' + content)
```

Comment: One problem with this: either the files already have a definition of `MY_CONSTANT` in place that will override the imported value, or the files aren't currently using `MY_CONSTANT`. Either way, additional editing will be needed, in which case there's little point in automating this part of the task.

Comment: @chepner That is true, but that's a problem with the question, not my answer. The question was just to add this line to multiple files, which my answer does.