# Insert string into html file using python beautifulsoup

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I want to insert a string like this `{% load static %}` into the first line (at the very top) of existing html files through using python (by Beautifulsoup if possible). So from this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the result to be like this. So i can run the python script and insert this line into all the existing html files i have.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `insert_before()` method to add a string before the `DOCTYPE`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.contents[0].insert_before('{% load static %} \n')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you are looking for here: [Prepend line to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file) you could just loop it and have it run for all the files you need to be updated.