# How to write file names which are in a certain directory + index of each line?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get the file names which are in a folder wrote into an output file with the index of each line. I am using the code below to write the filenames:

```
import os

with open("bionaplsatfiles.dat", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Bionapl_Nicolas\testKB\vtu_files\output_Sn'):
       for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(filename)
         a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

I am getting the result below:

```
Sat_t0.txt
Sat_t1.txt
Sat_t2.txt
Sat_t3.txt
Sat_t4.txt
Sat_t5.txt
```

But what I need is :

```
0   Sat_t0.txt
1   Sat_t1.txt
2   Sat_t2.txt
3   Sat_t3.txt
4   Sat_t4.txt
5   Sat_t5.txt
```

What should I add to my code to get the index column?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a counter variable. The code might look like this:

```py
import os

with open("bionaplsatfiles.dat", "w") as a:
    count = 0
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Bionapl_Nicolas\testKB\vtu_files\output_Sn'):
       for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(filename)
         a.write(f'{count} {str(f)}{os.linesep}')
         count += 1
```

Comment: this is copying my answer!

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't. I wrote my answer and didn't know that yours is already posted.

Comment: will, it does create a column for indexes but it gives me 0 in all the indexes !

Comment: Sorry, I realize that using `enumerate` just makes the solution complicated. Simply use a counter can solve the problem. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, it gives me what I need. 
One last question: do you have an idea how can I add the number of lines before the first line (in the same output that we just created)?

Comment: I can think of 2 options at the moment. 1st is: after creating the file, open it again and [prepend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914627/prepend-line-to-beginning-of-a-file) the final `count` to the file. The 2nd option is: instead of writing directly to the file inside the loop, just store all file names in a list. Then, open the file, write the `len(my_list) + 1` (should be the total lines), then looping through the list with `enumerate` to print out index and file names.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`:

```
import os

with open("bionaplsatfiles.dat", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Bionapl_Nicolas\testKB\vtu_files\output_Sn'):
       for index, filename in enumerate(files): # FIX
         f = os.path.join(filename)
         a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

[See the official documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: It does create a column for indexes but there all equal to 0! 
`0    Sat_t0.txt`
`0    Sat_t1.txt`
`0    Sat_t2.txt`
`0    Sat_t3.txt`

Comment: @Joelle, `enumerate` was applied in the wrong loop. Sorry about that. It should be working as you want now.