# How to write to beginning and end of every line in a text file?

Tags: python, file-io, text-files

I'm currently looking for a way to write to the beginning and end of every line of a text file in Python.

For example,

**Current TXT document:**

```
Jimmy
Was
Here
```

**Write the 1st VALUE to the beginning of every line**

```
111Jimmy
111Was
111Here
```

**Write the 2nd VALUE to the end of every line**

```
111Jimmy222
111Was222
111Here222
```

Can't seem to find anything on Google that describes how to properly have this done. I've found methods of writing to specific lines, but not all of them in this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python#125759

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
prefix = '111'
suffix = '222'

with open('source.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('dest.txt', 'w') as dest:
       for line in src:
           dest.write('%s%s%s\n' % (prefix, line.rstrip('\n'), suffix))
```

Comment: what if `suffix` is not fixed length string ?

Comment: @BehnamHeydari:  That should make no difference.

Comment: so the number of `%s` is not related to length of `suffix`?

Comment: @BehnamHeydari:  Correct.  Three `%s` means three items are being interpolated into the string.  Here the three items are the prefix, the line itself, and the suffix.

Comment: For people using Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings (but note, [can't put `\n` inside the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780467/2745495)): `ss = line.rstrip('\n'); dest.write(f"{prefix}{ss}{suffix}\n")`

Answer (score 5):

You can make changes to the file without opening multiple files by using [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) with `inplace=1`:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('test.txt', inplace=1):
    print '{0}{1}{2}'.format('111', line.rstrip('\n'), '222')
```

Comment: On Python 2.5 or below replace the print line with `print '%s%s%s' % ('111', line[:-1], '222')`

Comment: -1: NEVER use `line[:-1]`, in case the last line is not terminated. Use `line.rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read the file using readlines() in a list you can do

```
value1 = "" # appended at first
value2 = "" # appended at last
data = file.readlines()
data = [ ( value1 + str.rstrip('\n') + value2 + "\n" ) for str in data ]
```

and then write data back to the file....

Comment: This has to hold the entire file in memory, as opposed to Steven Rumbalski's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
f1o = open("input.txt", "r")
f2o = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in f1o:
    f2o.write("111%s222\n" % line.replace("\n"))

f1o.close()
f2o.close()
```

Comment: `replace` takes two arguments.