# How to prepend a text , Write To Beginning Every Line in TXT and end with an extra row

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a text file as shown below:

```
this is 1 line
this is 2 line
this is 3 line
```

I want to convert it into something like below:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is 1 line
\item this is 2 line
\item this is 3 line
\end{enumerate}
```

I am using the code below:

```
prefix = '\\item '

with open('new.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('dest.txt', 'w') as dest:
       dest.write("\\begin{enumerate}\n")
       for line in src:
           dest.write('%s%s\n' % (prefix, line.rstrip('\n')))
```

Reference : [Python - Write To Beginning and End of Every Line in TXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933472/python-write-to-beginning-and-end-of-every-line-in-txt)

But I can't seem to add the last line "\end{enumerate}" correctly. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line at the end of your `with` clause:

```
prefix = '\\item '

with open('new.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('dest.txt', 'w') as dest:
       dest.write("\\begin{enumerate}\n")
       for line in src:
           dest.write('%s%s\n' % (prefix, line.rstrip('\n')))
       dest.write("\\end{enumerate}\n")
```