# f-string formula inside curly brackets not working

Tags: python, f-string

I am on Python 3.7.

My code on line 3 works fine, however when I insert the underlying formula into line 4, my code returns the error:

**SyntaxError: f-string: mismatched '(', '{', or '['**
(the error points to the first '(' in line 4.

My code is:

```
cheapest_plan_point = 3122.54
phrase = format(round(cheapest_plan_point), ",")
print(f"1: {phrase}")
print(f"2: {format(round(cheapest_plan_point), ",")}")
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with line 4.

Comment: Use single quotes inside curly braces `print(f"2: {format(round(cheapest_plan_point), ',')}")`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You used `"` quotes inside a `"..."` delimited string.

Python sees:

```
print(f"2: {format(round(cheapest_plan_point), "
      ,
      ")}")
```

so the `)}` is a *new, separate string*.

Use different delimiters:

```
print(f"2: {format(round(cheapest_plan_point), ',')}")
```

*However*, you *don't need to use `format()` here*. In an f-string, you already are formatting each interpolated value! Just add `:,` to apply the formatting instruction directly to the `round()` result:

```
print(f"2: {round(cheapest_plan_point):,}")
```

The format `{expression:formatting_spec}` applies `formatting_spec` to the outcome of `expression`, just as if you used `{format(expression, 'formatting_spec')}`, but without having to call `format()` and without having to put the `formatting_spec` part in quotes.