# Why does F strings appear as invalid in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I just started using Python and I'm getting this weird bug in Visual Studio Code. I'm using F Strings and inside the editor, it says it's invalid syntax. [image]

Why does this have a red underline? It's apparently also invalid syntax even though the code does work correctly from the command prompt. [image]

The extensions I have enabled are Beautify, ESLint (the file is picking up as MagicPython down the bottom so I assume this doesn't affect it), MagicPython, Material Theme, Python, Visual Studio IntelliCode - Preview.
Thanks! Neeron.

Comment: VS Code is an awful python IDE. It's probably not aware of the 3.6 f-strings format (or some plugin isn't).

Comment: Have you figured it out yet cause I have same issue?

Comment: The new python pep https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/, show that the `new` way to format string is following this template. Maybe because of that the string is showing in a way that it looks wrong.

Comment: I am having the same issue in VS Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Python interpreter to a version that supports f-strings.

1. Click on the python version on the bottom right of your screen
   [image: select python interpreter position]
2. Select a newer python interpreter on the dropdown box.

The error should be gone now.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the extensions called python and I meet the same question like that.
[the question I meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEfDS.jpg) Just adjusting the version of python which is used by the extend can solve the problem.[change this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqehR.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).