# Discord.py - SyntaxError f-string: empty expression not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm getting a SyntaxError: `f-string: empty expression not allowed` I'm not sure (at all) what this means

I've tried moving around the code & looked online but I've got no different results

The code is:

```
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
 client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

 await ctx.send(f"Loaded the {} module!".format(extension))
```

It's for cogs & I'm sure I've got everything else right, I'm not sure though

If anyone knows what to do then please tell me, thx

Comment: Either use `f'...'` or `.format(..)` don't use both: `f"Loaded the {} module!".format(extension))`.

Comment: well now the Python console doesn't even want to open, it opens for a split second and then closes (I can see it's a traceback error but that's it, it opens with the IDLE console but I like to use the Python one)

Comment: Open it with cmd prompt and terminal and run it (it won't close after running).  That is a different issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is the empty {} in the f-string. F-strings require a variable name between the braces.
The line with the string should be:

```
await ctx.send(f"Loaded the {extension} module!")
```

Or

```
await ctx.send("Loaded the {} module!".format(extension))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep your code structure the way it is, you can also do like this:

```
await ctx.send(f"Loaded the {{}} module!".format(extension))
```