# syntax error while using f string in **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use **kwargs and facing a syntax error while using f-string in print function. I have no idea why it that an error? I'm using Python3.7.4 .

```
def func(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(f' {k} : {v} ')

func(first_name = 'x', last_name = 'y')

File "130819.py", line 4
    print(f' {k} : {v} ')
                       ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your code works fine: https://ideone.com/Ci1woh. Make sure you copied the correct code and check your python version you're using to run this script

Comment: please check the version of python , as f-string are not present in python2 ...

Comment: This code works perfectly on 3.6.8 and I can't see why it wouldn't on 3.7.4. Are you sure you're not using 2.7.4 instead ???

Comment: I can also confirm that this works fine in both Python 3.6.8 and 3.7.3.

Comment: I am using Linux and I have 3 different Python versions installed on the system. By default, I have Python2 set as an interpreter. Using Python3 as the command solved the syntax error, Thanks y'all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code works fine with python 3.7 and gives the expected output

```
 def func(**kwargs):
...     for k, v in kwargs.items():
...         print(f' {k} : {v} ')
... 
 func(first_name = 'x', last_name = 'y')
```

output is

```
 first_name : x 
 last_name : y
```

*I think the problem is with your python version , as f-string literals are present only in python 3.6 +*

Try to check the version with `python --version`