# Giving "Invalid Syntax" error with a format function

Tags: python, syntax, format

Here is the code:

```
def print_variables(vars):
    for i in range(len(vars)):
        print(f"{i + 1}:  {vars[i]}")


print_variables(["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow"])
```

On the 3rd line it is giving the error "Invalid Syntax" and I don't know why. I am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are on an older version of Python when [f'strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) weren't introduced. So please upgrade to python 3.6 or newer. Otherwise, do this:
For python 3.x:

```
print("{0}:  {1}".format((i+1),(vars[i])))
```

For Python 2.x:

```
print "%s:  %s" % ((i+1),(vars[i]))
```

Comment: When I type 'python' on cmd it says that I have python 3.7.4.

Comment: Are you running the program on cmd or some other IDE?

Comment: I tried it on idle and it showed the same error. It doesn't work on CMD either

Comment: My question is, does the code give error when run on cmd? And can you check the version of python in your ide, with `import sys` `print(sys.version)`

Comment: I think the python environment in your IDE is different than your system-level python.

Comment: On cmd it says 3.7.4 -- CMD

Comment: But on IDLE is says 2.7.16 -- I wiill find out how to update IDLE

Comment: Then on cmd, your original code should work. If it doesn't then there is an issue. If it does, then there is version compatibility issue with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in python 3.7.4. It was introduced from 3.6. check this [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)
If python version you are using is below 3.6, it may be the reason that it is giving an error.