# Getting a snytax error when creating a Jupyter book on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter

I have installed the Jupyter-book module in Python. On Windows 10, I run this command:

```
jupyter-book create mybookname
```

I get an syntax error, ending with this in the trace:

File "c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_book\build.py", line 92
    f"{path_book}"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any ideas of what the syntax error is here? This is Python 3.5.3.

Comment: My first guess is that you've imported a Python 3.8 package into an older Python interpreter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Comment: The answers below have helped. I didn't realize I needed Python >=3.6. Upgrading has fixed things.

Answer (score 2):

`f"{path_book}"` -- this is [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498), only available [since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)
Try to create your notebook with Python 3.6 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

jupyter-book requires python >=3.6.

Check it here: https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-book/