# I can't get this code to work can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? subl says theres an error on line 18 but really can't figure it out

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using this code to practice BOF but can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket, sys
from time import sleep

buffer = b'A' * 100

while True:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('192.168.71.141, 9999'))
        s.close()
        sleep(2)

        buffer = buffer + b'A' * 100

    except:
        print(f"Fuzzing crashed at {str(len(buffer))} bytes.")
        sys.exit()
```

The error message:

```
File "/root/home_lab/py3fuzz", line 18
    print(f"Fuzzing crashed at {str(len(buffer))} bytes.")
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I updated it with the error.

Comment: I ran your code.... Nothing wrong with it. I think Daniel Martin is correct. Check your Python version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're using an old version of python, specifically a version 3.5 or earlier.

What does `python3 --version` say?

If possible, you should upgrade to a version of python 3.6 or higher, as python 3.5 is no longer supported.

If that isn't possible, don't use f-string syntax. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
    print("Fuzzing crashed at %s bytes." % (len(buffer),) )
```

Comment: I'm using version 3.9.1. I couldn't get it to work with that line either.. Starting to think I'm rerarted.

Comment: @Hellcatwarrior Maybe you think you are running Python 3.9.1, but really using a lower-version. The full error in the Traceback should show the current Python version you are running.