# python f string function SyntaxError: invalid syntax in linux

Tags: python, linux

I have a variable that using python f-string function:

```
test = 'hello'
sql2 = f"INSERT INTO EULA_STG_DATA ({test}) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)"
print(sql2 )
```

output:

```
'INSERT INTO EULA_STG_DATA (hello) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)'
```

this code has no problem running in Windows,but once run in Linux,it returns:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: Show us the full error message!

Comment: F-string is supported only in Python 3.6+, which your Linux environment likely does not have.

Comment: Which versiion of python are you using on Linux?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror