# Why does my basic print statement work, but my f-string version produces a syntax error?

Tags: python, printing, f-string

Very early stages of learning Python, and trying to complete 100 days of code challenge. Am building a crude blackjack game, but am stuck on what I am sure is probably a very simple fix that I don't recognise!

This is my code so far:

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

players = ["player", "dealer"]

players_hands = {}
players_scores = {}


for player in players:

    cards = random.choices(cards, k = 2)
    players_hands[player] = cards
    players_scores[player] = sum(cards)
    
print(players_hands["player"])

print(players_scores["player"])

print(f"Your cards: {players_hands["player"]}, current score: {players_scores["player"]}")

print(f"Dealer's first card: {players_hands["dealer"][0]}")**
```

I want to print the f-string version rather than the basic print statement, but keep getting a syntax error and don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: which version of python are you using? Which version introduced the f-string?

Comment: "keep getting a syntax error"—Saying what exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [f-strings giving SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50401632/3890632)

Comment: @khelwood That could be a factor, but I believe there is an actual syntax error here.

Comment: @Kemp That's why I didn't close the question. The OP needs to give more information about what error they are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that you are using at least Python 3.6, which f-strings were introduced in, but also...

You are using double quotes to access the dictionary, which is conflicting with using double quotes for the string. Try changing to either

```
print(f"Dealer's first card: {players_hands['dealer'][0]}")
```

or

```
print(f'Dealer\'s first card: {players_hands["dealer"][0]}')
```

Comment: thanks, I keep forgetting that rule! works perfectly now. thanks for your time! 8)