# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ieuser\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-kpbujv\pyinstaller\ in windows

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hi I am trying to install pyinstaller in my virtual windows 10 but I am getting this error. ["python setup.py egg_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg8GD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

looks like a invalid syntax in the installation files

maybe do to a pip or python version issue with pyinstaller?

what 2.7 py version are you on

it also tells you about the pip error