# SyntaxError when trying to print a string and a variable in an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, syntax-error

My code is supposed to loop through a list of simple equations (e.g. 1+1 = 2), split the equations from the answers, and then ask the user the equation. I'm getting a SyntaxError on the line where it prints the equation, and I think it has to do with the combination of the variable and the tring since it runs fine when there is no variable inserted.

```
for question in questions:       #iterate through each of the questions
equation = question.split('=')   #split the equations into a question and an answer
temp = str(equation[0])
print(f'{equation[0]}=')
answer = input()  #Prompt user for answer to equation
if answer == int(equation[1]):   #Compare user answer to real answer
    score +=1                    #If answer correct, increase score
```

What am I missing here?

clarifications:
SORRY! made a mistake and copied my test code. The important line:
print(f'{equation[0]}=')
has been corrected.

Indentation is identical to what is posted.
equation list looks like:

```
1+1=2
2+2=4
44-15=29
1x2=2
```

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/nsuess/PycharmProjects/Quiz/exercise.py", line 28
    answer = input(f'{equation[0]}=')  #Prompt user for answer to equation
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Update:**
I found that if I change the line to:
response = input(equation[0])
then it runs fine, but I need to add an '=' to the end according to the problem statement. When I use print, it puts it on a new line. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the question list?

Comment: Is your indentation identical to what you have in your program?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete working code (yours has an indentation error and is missing `questions`), input, expected output, and actual output, i.e. the full error message. You can [edit]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: What does your error traceback say? Aside from the intention, the syntax error in the print line comes from the fstring if using Python3.5 or lower

Comment: Indentation is identical to what is posted. equation list looks like: 
1+1=2
2+2=4
44-15=29
1x2=2
can't tell about formatting, but it's one equation per line

Comment: @NickSuess you should edit your question to add this info instead of posting it into comments

Comment: If the error is at `print(f'{temp}')`, maybe the problem is that the version of Python you're using doesn't support f-strings. Either way, that f-string is redundant: use `print(temp)` instead.

Comment: Duplicate: [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question list is similar to the following:

```
questions = ['2 + 2 = 4', '3 - 1 = 2', '2 * 4 = 8']
```

This is how I would proceed:

```
score = 0
for question in questions:
    temp = question.split('=')
    equation = temp[0].strip()
    answer = temp[1].strip()
    resp = input(equation)
    if resp == answer:
        score += 1
print(score)
```

Comment: This runs when I put it in my code. I think it may have something to do with the .strip, because other than that it looks almost identical to me. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I just noticed that you have:
    resp = input(equation)
and I have 
    response = input(f'{equation[0]}=')
So your code runs because you're not mixing a variable and a string into the input... Maybe I'll try printing the variable first

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My IDE was using python 2.7 instead of 3.6 which was needed to print a string and a variable in the same line.