# What's wrong with the syntax in Python in Google Colab in my google accunt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, google-colaboratory, f-string

For a week now I have noticed this in my account on different notebooks. the situation with the syntax. Python stopped seeing f-lines. And the print function began to display everything in brackets for some reason.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Irreproducible for me

Comment: try this : `print(f"x={x}")`

Comment: you are using Python 2

Comment: You are using a `python2` runtime in google colab. There should be a warning displayed when you run a cell. I suspect you opened an old notebook with a `python2`  runtime. You can change it under `Runtime -> Change runtime Type`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are using Python 2. F-strings were added in Python 3.6, as you can see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror), so they don't work in any older version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually narrow this code down to:

```
>>> print(f'{x=}')
x=5
>>>
```

Comment: This works in the newest version, but the output (3.9.5) is a string