# python code working fine in my parrot os but showing error on ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

code working fine on parrot os but showing error on ubuntu

```
def count_down(count):
count_min = math.floor(count/60)
count_sec = count%60
if count_min<10:
    count_min=f"0{count_min}"
if count_sec<10 :
    count_sec=f"0{count_sec}"
```

error shown is

```
count_min=f"0{count_min}"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what version of python is being run on both? f-strings are >3.6

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror

Comment: Python 3.8.10 on ubuntu where error was shown

Comment: Are you _very_ certain? That's the exact error you'd get running that code in, say, Python 2. Check that `python` means the same thing on both operating systems, or run `python38 yourscript` (or similar as appropriate) to force it.

Comment: python on parrot is 3.9 and both python --version and python3 --version showing 3.9

Comment: python on ubuntu python --version 2.7 and python3 --version 3.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved when i ran the file in vs code this error was shown

```
count_min=f"0{count_min}"
                        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i tried python3 main.py and this error was shown

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

so i did `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

and my app is working fine