# Why isn't it possible to use backslashes inside the braces of f-strings? How can I work around the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, backslash, f-string

In Python >=3.6, f-strings can be used as a replacement for the `str.format` method. As a simple example, these are equivalent:

```
'{} {}'.format(2+2, "hey")
f'{2+2} {"hey"}'
```

Disregarding [format specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers), I can basically move the positional arguments of `str.format` inside braces in an f-string. Note specifically that I am allowed to just put `str` literals in here, although it may seem a bit unwieldy.

There are however some limitations. Specifically, [backslashes in any shape or form](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences) are disallowed inside the braces of an f-string:

```
'{}'.format("new\nline")  # legal
f'{"new\nline"}'          # illegal
f'{"\\"}'                 # illegal
```

I cannot even use `\` to split up a long line if it's inside the braces;

```
f'{2+\
2}'     # illegal
```

even though this usage of `\` is perfectly allowed inside normal `str`'s;

```
'{\
}'.format(2+2)  # legal
```

It seems to me that a hard stop is coded into the parser if it sees the `\` character at all inside the braces of an f-string. Why is this limitation implemented? Though the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences) specify this behavior, it does not justify why.

Comment: See [Let’s make escaping in f-literals impossible](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-August/041727.html) and the conclusion [Changes to PEP 498 (f-strings)](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-August/145979.html)

Comment: I too think this violates 'Principle of Least Astonishment'. Actually I was surprised that it didn't accept "\n" character. I write Ruby code for living and you can write all sorts of syntactically correct Ruby code in `#{}` interpolation

Comment: Starting with Python 3.12, it [is possible](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-701-syntactic-formalization-of-f-strings).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to expect

```
'{}'.format("new\nline")
```

and

```
f'{"new\nline"}'
```

to be equivalent. That's not what I would expect, and it's not how backslashes in f-strings worked back in the pre-release versions of Python 3.6 where backslashes between the braces were allowed. Back then, you'd get an error because

```
"new
line"
```

is not a valid Python expression.

As just demonstrated, backslashes in the braces are confusing and ambiguous, and they were [banned](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-August/145979.html) to avoid confusion:

> The point of this is to disallow convoluted code like:
>
> ```
> >>> d = {'a': 4}
> >>> f'{d[\'a\']}'
> '4'
> ```
>
> In addition, I'll disallow escapes to be used for brackets, as in:
>
> ```
> >>> f'\x7bd["a"]}'
> '4'
> ```
>
> (where chr(0x7b) ==  "{").

Comment: Agreed backslashes in braces are confusing, but backslashes outside are not permitted either and that is too bad. This example is not confusing: `f"Make your selection \n A- {textA} \n B- {textB} \n C- {textC}"`.

Comment: @Guimoute: But then the question arises of whether `\{` or `\x7b` start a replacement field.

Comment: True. Maybe only `\n`, `\t` and `\r` could be allowed. Surprisingly I just found out that `f"/!\\ caution"` raises no error and it prints fine.

Comment: @Guimoute Your non-confusing example is perfectly legal (in Python 3.7.8, at least): `f"Make your selection \n A- {textA} \n B- {textB} \n C- {textC}"`. I believe backslashes are only disallowed *inside* braces.

Comment: @StevenOxley Yes, I have no problem with that example now. Unfortunately I have no idea whether that was the case at the time of the original comment, 2+ years ago.

Answer (score 13):

It's annoying that you can't do this:

```
things = ['Thing one','Thing two','Thing three']
print(f"I have a list of things: \n{'\n'.join(things)}")
```

But you can do this:

```
things = ['Thing one','Thing two','Thing three']
nl = '\n'
print(f"I have a list of things:\n{nl.join(things)}")
```

Comment: Also the use of textwrap.dedent is totally broken for multi-line f-strings, as the default case is to begin the dedent with a line-continuation `dedent('''\\`. This is plain broken imo and the bizarre purist attitudes like this from the py3 devs only serve to hurt the user.

Comment: @Rebs: Beginning an f-string with a line continuation works fine: https://ideone.com/OM7Fxd

Comment: Starting with Python 3.12 your first code snippet [works](https://peps.python.org/pep-0701/)

Answer (score 6):

For **new lines**, you can use `os.linesep` instead of `\n`. For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> print(f"Numbers:\n{os.linesep.join(map(str, [10, 20, 30]))}")
Numbers:
10
20
30
```

Comment: The correct line separator for `print` is `'\n'` on all platforms, but on Windows `os.linesep` is `'\r\n'` ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep)). I think `'\n' == chr(10)` is guaranteed, so you can write `chr(10).join(...)`, though it feels hacky.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this helps, but instead of the illegal

```py
f'{"new\nline"}'
```

one could use

```py
f'{"new"+chr(10)+"line"}'
```